# Very low contrast syntax highlighting on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, mobile-web, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighting for mobile on Android Chrome seems to be using a different set of colours, which looks much worse on mobile browsers (true over multiple SE sites)

Here's a side by side comparison (click through for the source of the screenshots):

[image: Example VBA question]

mobile browser desktop site on the left, mobile browser mobile site (looking worse) on the right.

More zoomed out and for larger blocks of code, syntax highlighting becomes basically useless for the mobile site. This is for VBA, but I'm sure it's an issue for other languages too. Is it possible to update the mobile site to use the latest colours?

Comment: Worth noting that the colours on mobile are not the same as the former desktop colours (before the recent changes). They are less readable then the previous desktop ones or the current ones. Also can anyone repro or is it maybe just some setting I'm using in my phone?

Comment: I checked several languages, the colors are certainly different (and worse) on mobile website. One more reason to use responsive design (full site). :)

Comment: @ahmedus Is this responsive full site something that exists yet? The "request desktop site" on my phone seems very bad for mobile (tiny text). Sorry I'm not really familiar with how websites work

Comment: You will see a "full site" link on the footer if viewing the site on mobile.

Comment: @Greedo you shouldn't enable "request desktop site" on your phone. Just leave it at the default which should be not desktop site. And click full site in the footer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've officially switched to [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) network-wide. See the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/395497) for more details.

Comment: Well that's cool but for this specific example it's made things a bit worse - now for VBA there appears to be no syntax highlighting on the mobile or responsive sites - I think maybe because VBA never had its own highlighter and used VB.net? highlight.js supports vbscript which would be the best substitute I think

Comment: @Greedo ah, yikes! Looking into this today. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354544/395497) for updates as I have them

Comment: @Greedo I've fixed the vbscript non-highlighting issues. Please see the aforementioned post for details. Thanks for bringing it to my attention