# Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter

Tags: discussion, design, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

### Update 2020-09-24

This is now live network-wide.

### Update

This is now live on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow. Any bugs and feedback can be posted here as an answer.

---

I’m Ben and I’m a dev on the **Teams** team here at Stack Overflow - we're the team focused on building the private Teams experience on SO. I’ve recently been working on our post editing experience and I’d like to show off some preliminary work that’s coming to the network soon.

### TL;DR

We’re switching our code block highlighting library from Google Prettify to [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/). All your favorite languages are still supported and you won’t need to change how you write posts at all. The only major change is how we *render* highlighted code blocks. In addition, we’re taking this opportunity to introduce our new highlighting theme as well. We’re rolling this out in stages, starting with MSE/MSO with other sites to follow. (See the FAQ at the bottom of this post for dates)

### Some history on Prettify / code block highlighting

I tried to do some digging on when we first adopted Prettify, but it seems that its history goes allll the way back to site’s earliest days. [The earliest reference I could find was from back in ‘08](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28275/395497). I asked around internally too and the best answers I could get were along the lines of:

> ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ *- Everyone*

> Ask Atwood *- [Dean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/267572/dean-ward)*

and

> If I had to guess, it was something along the lines of "there's not a lot of options, and this is used by Google so it's probably fine" *- [Kevin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose)*

Eventually the wonderful [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) pointed me to [Stack Overflow Podcast #11](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/06/26/podcast-11/), aired June 2008, where Jeff and Joel talk about how incredible it was for the time and how Google uses it themselves for syntax highlighting in Google Code (RIP). They also put out a call for alternatives, which I’d have to assume came up short.

### Why the change?

Google Prettify hasn't been under active development for a while, and was [officially discontinued by Google in April](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify/commit/e006587b4a893f0281e9dc9a53001c7ed584d4e7), as you all have [let us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251321/google-code-prettify-seems-dead) [know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289694/a-stack-exchange-fork-of-google-prettify) [repeatedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738/google-code-prettify-has-been-officially-discontinued-its-time-for-se-to-maint). This means that no new language syntaxes<sup>1</sup> are being supported and that existing language syntaxes aren’t getting updated to support all their new features. It’s time to move on to something that supports modern front-end workflows (such as providing an npm package, for starters) and continues to evolve to meet the needs of developers.

### What’s changing about how I write posts?

Absolutely nothing :). There is absolutely no change to how posts are written. We still support all the Prettify [language aliases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/395497) you know and love, along with the [new aliases](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) from highlight.js. *However*, we are not adding support for any *new* languages at this time, instead choosing to keep the initial changeset simple and aiming for current feature parity instead. All the current markdown syntax is still supported, along with determining code highlighting from tags and site defaults.

### So what *is* changing?

The “only” changes are visual. We are updating the client-side code block *renderer* that styles your code in posts (Questions, Answers, etc) and in the editor preview. Syntax autodetection when a language is not specified should be much better overall, along with syntax highlighting coverage in general. The biggest outward facing change for the typical user is going to be our new theme (see below for details).

### Why highlight.js? Why not…

Why did we pick highlight.js over Prettify? Well, first off, you [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126608/why-doesnt-stackoverflow-use-highlight-js-instead-of-google-code-prettify) [for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242456/switching-to-highlight-js-for-syntax-highlighting) [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please) specifically. More convincingly, it’s [open source](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/), [actively maintained](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/releases), and overall just a solid product.

We’re extremely concerned about performance here at SO (both on the client and on the server), so we needed to ensure that this major change on our hottest page on the site didn’t negatively impact our users. There was some prior investigation into highlight.js's performance [back in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279361/395497), but I figured we should give it another shot.

In our internal performance benchmarks highlight.js scored better than Prettify consistently across all browsers (except macOS Safari 13.1, where it was actually a bit slower)<sup>2</sup>. It is a *tad* heavier than Prettify<sup>3</sup>, weighing in at an extra ~17kB (over the wire) after including all the languages we support across the network. This extra weight gain was acceptable to us as a tradeoff for what we were getting in return.

Why did we pick highlight.js over other contenders? Simply put, it was the best option that served our needs. We needed a library that we could easily control for use in the browser (deferred loading, theming specific elements), while also being simple to consume via a npm package, not needing specific build steps or a special babel plugin to pull in only the parts we need. Additionally, we could run it on the server (via Node.js) to unify our syntax highlighting in our [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) documentation, giving us a single syntax highlighter across our products. Also a major plus was the ability to tokenize the highlighting result for use in our new editor (stay tuned!).

### What are some potential drawbacks?

The most obvious not-quite-a-drawback is that language autodetection is different from Prettify. In general, it will be much more accurate, but will possibly end up with a different result that what Prettify would give us. This isn’t so much a bad thing, as it is just a thing that might take some getting used to if you’re a Prettify power user.

As mentioned earlier, the overall code bundle size is a bit bigger too. The vast majority of users wouldn’t even notice the change, which would only affect the first fetch since the browser will cache the file locally for subsequent hits anyways.

The last item is a bit of a personal preference. highlight.js tends to not highlight punctuation, which makes it a bit less colorful than other highlighters. This is [considered a feature](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/1296#issuecomment-246226256). Not a deal breaker by any means, but something I should mention regardless.

### Designing the new theme

To offer some insight into how the new theme was designed, I reached out to the author, principal design systems designer [Aaron Shekey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey).

> Since we’re upgrading, we wanted to take this opportunity to design a Stack Overflow-flavored theme that takes advantage of newer tech like CSS variables that are aware of both light and dark modes. While we’ve improved it over the years, it’s highly likely that the current production theme simply used the stock colors provided by Prettify.
>
> We’d need a theme that could work in both light and dark modes, was informed by Stack Overflow’s branded colors, and introduced a bit more contrast throughout.
>
> Thankfully, we weren’t starting from scratch. When we built our Stacks documentation, we’d spent some time making our Jekyll theme display code snippets that got pretty close to accomplishing those goals. However, this was before dark mode was a thing, and we’d only built a single theme that assumed a fixed dark background. We’d have to extend this theme to light mode and revisit contrast along the way.
>
> Using the [Stacks documentation](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/code-blocks/) as a playground, we’ve now got themes in both light and dark modes that look like Stack Overflow and add or maintain contrast levels. We did our best to accomplish a contrast level of AAA, with a few variables dipping into AA. You can see the exact measurements commented in our [colors](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/blob/develop/lib/css/exports/_stacks-constants-colors.less#L296-L307) [constants](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/blob/develop/lib/css/exports/_stacks-constants-colors.less#L438-L449) file.

Here are a few screencaps of the new theme taken from my local development environment (click on the images to expand them). You can preview more languages (with an easy dark/light mode toggle) over at the [Stacks docs](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/code-blocks/).

#### Before

[image: hljs before]

#### After

[image: hljs after]

### FAQ

- Q: When is the rollout happening?

  A: We're planning to roll this out to meta.stackexchange and meta.stackoverflow on **Thursday, September 10th**. Rollout to the rest of the network is scheduled for **September 24th**, after the initial testing period. This is a *soft* rollout date, dependent on any bugs/feedback we get from the community during the testing period.
- Q: What if I find a bug?

  A: Report bugs in an answer (one per answer) to this question. We'll keep this open for a couple/few weeks (until **Friday, October 2nd**) to address any immediate issues and then we'll update this post and ask you to post bugs as new questions after that time.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> I checked, plural of *syntax* [is syntaxes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/plural-of-syntax). Take *that* spell-checker!

<sup>2</sup> Client-side benchmarks being what they are, we measured anywhere from ~49%-60% increase in the rate of ops/second depending on the machine and browser. Outliers being Safari 13.1 which had a ~29% *decrease* (favoring prettify) and Edge “legacy” scoring a ~279% increase over prettify!

<sup>3</sup> Size comparisons were done comparing the `prettify-full.en.js` file taken from production vs the new `highlight.pack.js` bundle. Both were minified and served via a [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) instance with the [compress flag](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercompress) set (enabling gzip support). They were then included onto a regular html page with `script` tags and measured using the built-in browser dev tools. At the time of measurement, prettify landed at `23.3kB` over the wire (meaning that the file was minified + gzipped) vs highlight.js at `40.7kB`. This is a `17.4kB` increase or about a ~74% increase in file size.

Comment: Good to see that the Teams devs are also bringing features to the public network!

Comment: I have some updating to do then, for example on this one: [What is the default language for the syntax highlighter?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327677/578411) ...

Comment: @rene I have a (incomplete, I'm sure) list of posts that need updating after this goes live. I'll add this one to the list. Thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: I hope the syntax highlighting FAQs (both [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) and [on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)) are part of that list as well.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Yup, they both are! Thanks for checking in though. Better safe than sorry with those posts since they're the "source of truth" for this feature.

Comment: How badly does it choke when asked to highlight [the omni-glot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210705/19365)?  (Yes, that's a single piece of code that's a different valid program in each of 294 languages.)

Comment: @Mark Honestly, not too bad. Speed was (visually, didn't actually benchmark it) comparable to my test page that had ~16 different languages on it. For the curious, the autohighlight detection marked that code snippet as `bash`.

Comment: Just a curious question: why continue to use a third-party syntax highlighter, rather than have an internal official syntax highlighter that was maintained by SE employees?

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog why invest resources into something that isn't the core product?

Comment: @Braiam I thought SO was their core product. Syntax highlighting is a core part of that.

Comment: Q&A is the core product, @Sonic, not syntax highlighters. Syntax highlighting is just a small portion of that, and not in any way critical to the platform's success. It isn't something Stack Overflow needs ownership or control of. Just as you shouldn't develop your own JavaScript framework, you shouldn't develop all your own tools when there's something already out there that does the job well.

Comment: Given that highlighting occurs client side, how about a feature that allows the user to specify the highlight.js template(s)? It would be very cool if code on SO looked the same as my IDE. Familiar (color) styling makes code easier to read.

Comment: Are there regression tests in place that verify the risk of breaking changes being minimal?

Comment: Please, ask your questions as answers, as that gives Ben more room to respond individually!

Comment: Whatever you do, please [don't change the `line-height` for code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353525/401803)

Comment: Cool :) Does this mean `lang-elixir` will finally get explicit syntax highlighting support?

Comment: Does that imply that we finally get highlighting of a language’s actual keywords, instead of some random words picked up from different languages? That would be great.

Comment: AT LAST typescript support. It's only 7 years old...

Comment: @hkotsubo I thought they did that already.  It *is* back to normal now, though...the code-block line-height.

Comment: Does highlight.js support [in-code emphasis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371782/lets-fork-google-prettify-library)?

Comment: Don't forget to update [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to mention highlight.js instead of Google Prettify.

Comment: @Clonkex Already good to go! You can see the update on the [meta version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) of that page (happens automatically when turned on). Good looking out though

Comment: @Bohemian No, not that I'm aware of. We could add `diff` language support somewhere down the line, but that has its own problems when it comes to highlighting

Comment: @Ben just to be clear, any such feature would have to work for all languages. It would be a cross-cutting concern. Is forking highlight.js and using our own version an option?

Comment: When are the meta post updates in your list going to occur?

Comment: Please revert to prettify or fix the colors with google. There is just no diplomatic way to put this -- the new syntax colors for C/C++ syntax hilighting are God-Awful Ugly -- it makes code harder to read.

Comment: I suggest to add an alias `lang-xaml` to `lang-xml`. It worked before update.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There was a bug that was causing some conflicting styling on some of our language features. I've fixed it and most languages will now look _much_ better

Comment: I'm glad it finally happened :-) (P.S. I'd use a different color for .hljs-meta from the one used for keywords.)

Comment: @BenKelly Thank you for checking. However I just looked at another C question and the `#include <....>` are "baby-puke green" and all functions are "burned orange", strings are the same "baby-puke green", etc.. I just looked at [I'm trying to make a diagram of fork() process calls in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64070663/3422102). I don't know what to say, but with dark-mode the syntax highlight is horrible. (I have three kids -- I know baby puke green...)

Comment: it doesn't work at all for the prolog tag on SO unless we specify "lang-prolog" manually, and even then the new highlighter is atrociously erratic. most of the times even "language-all: lang-prolog" doesn't work and one has to re-do all code snippets one by one, some times it's the other way around. for examples, see my recent edits to posts in prolog. no, I won't prepare the brief, I've burned enough time on this as it is. it worked reasonably well before you went on your crusade du jour to fix what wasn't broken in the first place. oh, and "erlang" is completely messed up.

Comment: @WillNess Looks like the prolog tag on SO specifies "none" for highlighting and "lang-prolog" isn't in the list of options. Not 100% sure how we populate that list off the top of my head, but we'll look into it on Monday. I switched it to "default" for now so that should hopefully help, but please let me know if it somehow makes things worse instead.

Comment: @AdamLear take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8882745/9). all the code snippets are done with code fences with the same lang-prolog specified. yet the highlighting for some looks completely different than for others. this is just supposed to be impossible, isn't it? besides, the highlighting itself is not good at all even when it works, like with the very first snippet there.

Comment: @AdamLear here's another reference: see these two answers, both on the same question, both have no lang specs whatever, the highlighting half-works on [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19995241/849891) and doesn't on the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983680/849891). (re "half-works": `%` is EOL-comments char in Prolog. yet it looks differently in the different snippets)

Comment: @AdamLear [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64048419/5) yet another example. both code snippets are tagged with `prolog`, yet look completely different. nothing changes when I change it to `lang-prolog`, too. the highlighting is ***completely broken***.

Comment: @AdamLear lastly, :) [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20102528/4) "`erlang`" highlighting -- absolutely erratic, inconsistent within one code block even. compare it with the previous highlighter's beautiful [results](http://web.archive.org/web/20200831110557/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318888/solving-who-owns-the-zebra-programmatically) (search for "CLP" to quickly jump to it there on that page) ([the image](https://imgur.com/a/dwGYobq))

Comment: @BenKelly I’ve *partially* updated the FAQs as they sorely needed to be in light of new bug reports that need to be directed to highlight.js. Were you still going to update those?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup! That's on the list for updating today. Thank you for your help! *Edit - updated!*

Comment: @WillNess `Prolog` is not one of our [supported languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/395497), so it'll get autohighlighted to whatever highlight.js thinks the snippet most closely resembles. The `erlang` issue you note appears to be an upstream issue. I'd recommend filing a bug report.

Comment: @BenKelly no, explicit lang-prolog works, but only sometimes. do you *really* suggest it's alright for the highlighter to switch to something else even when there's an explicit spec of the language on each snippet??? how *odd*. re bug report, I've burned enough time on this as it is. if you want your site to work properly, you do it. you get the dough for it, I don't, with all due respect.

Comment: @WillNess I can tell you with confidence that `prolog` does **not** work. There's simply no syntax definition loaded for it. You can inspect the dom of the `pre` element and you can see the language it autohighlights as (added as a class). Any "correct" highlighting you're seeing is coincidental. It didn't work correctly in the past either. When prettify couldn't detect a language, it would highlight literally everything it could as a last-ditch effort. See the [Meta.SO announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401031/10060195) for more details on autohighlighting differences.

Comment: @BenKelly aha. thanks for this clarification. I thought lang-prolog and prolog were different. --- what I did before was I always used erlang, and it worked well enough. but now that's broken. so, a change for the worst for us in prolog, overall. IOW, progress. :-L //moving on...

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459610/59081) is horribly broken in terms of highlight.

Comment: Wow, came here after trying to understand why Objective C is unreadable on stack overflow nowadays. I mean, [almost everything is plain white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910192/reversegeocodelocation-stored-as-nsstring-producing-error) - and it's not like there is no definitive style of highlighting Objective C that everybody uses (Xcode...)!

Comment: @Ecuador Please create a new answer below and tag it as “bug”! (Highlight.js supports Objective-C, Stack Overflow just fails to apply that, it resorts to plain C instead).

Comment: I liked how it looked before :D but good to know the devs are responding to the community

Comment: @Ecuador ObjectiveC is a hard one to highlight because it's so dependent on punctuation. `[]` dispatch syntax, etc... which Highlight.js has traditionally not even tried to highlight (though we're more open to that now).  Or you could be seeing any number of issues with SO's specific implementation.  There (IMHO) are some serious issues with how they handle conflicting language tags and the version they are using is 10.2.0 while the latest (with many fixes) is 10.3.1.  If none of that helps we'd love your help to improve the ObjectiveC grammar if possible. :-)

Comment: @AdamLear That erlang example looks quite broken... please file an issue on our GitHub and we'd be happy to take a closer look at it.

Comment: @JoshGoebel Thanks, will do.

Comment: I don't know where to post this and didn't want to make a whole post about it, but the syntax highlighting for C# is pretty poor after this change. I've been stuck a couple times trying to get the syntax highlighting to take effect only to realize that the completely white code *was* the "syntax highlighting". Other languages (TypeScript) are similar, where almost nothing but keywords are highlighted and everything else is just white; white method names, white variables, white operators, white type names, etc.etc.

Comment: @Dave Cousineau: Yes, here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076915/why-does-my-textbox-round-up-an-amount-to-10-decimal-places#comment120273604_67076915) I stumbled upon yesterday.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/3251

Answer (score 182):

### Can Stack Exchange please update to newer versions of Highlight.js on a regular cycle, rather than only on request?

As I said in my [prior post reporting Google's discontinuation of Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738/google-code-prettify-has-been-officially-discontinued-its-time-for-se-to-maint), the process of filing bugs and feature requests with syntax highlighting would be quite drawn out and take a needlessly long time. The process was like this:

1. File a bug with Prettify, which would take 6-8 months to be resolved, if at all. (I filed a bug in 2014 and it still hadn't been resolved by the time Google put the project to rest.)
2. Once the request was resolved in Prettify, file another feature request here on Meta to request that SE update to the newer version. This would take the typical 6-8 week response time, but would often take longer than most requests because as far as I can best tell, they were only actioned when a developer happened to stumble on them.

As far as I can tell, Highlight.js is very actively maintained and requests with it are resolved fairly quickly, so #1 isn't an issue anymore (at least not in the current term). However, #2 will still remain an issue if SE sticks with their pre-existing model of only updating to newer versions on request.

Can Stack Exchange please actively update to newer Highlight.js versions on a regular cycle (not necessarily *immediately* after they're released, as I understand that'd be too onerous), rather than only updating to newer highlighter versions upon request? This would eliminate the problem in #2 and make the overall process significantly faster as one need only file the bug or feature request with Highlight.js and it'd be fixed in SE fairly quickly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1527/syntax-highlighting-discussion).

Answer (score 117):

I found it rather frustrating that I couldn't easily see how the before/after pictures differed, so I did a bit of cutting and pasting so I could look at the before/after side by side to compare them more easily. Then it occurred to me that others might like to do the same, so feel free to have a look. Should be the same basic info as in the question, but arranged for more meaningful viewing.

First dark mode:

[image]

And then light mode:

[image]

Sorry, my cutting wasn't quite perfect, so (especially in light mode) you can see some dark lines that really shouldn't be there. But even if there's a little extra junk, at least you can do a real comparison so the changes are reasonably apparent.

To me, the new color scheme appears to have at least a couple of different general types of problems.

One is technical accuracy (i.e., accuracy in the tokenization itself). For example, looking at the Python example, `if` is in one color, and `None` in a different color (which appears to be the same color for `0`, `1`, and `0b101` and for `someFunc` and `SomeClass`). `if` and `None` are both keywords, so it would appear reasonable that they both be the same color. It doesn't seem reasonable or useful for two keywords to be in clearly different colors, and one of them in the same color as some identifiers and literal values.

Another is the choices of colors themselves. Generally speaking, for comfortable viewing we want to balance between two extremes. If there's too little difference between colors, it's not always clear whether two things are the same or different colors. When colors can't be distinguished easily, we lose much of the benefit of using coloring to start with.

At the same time, we don't want too much contrast, especially when two things are immediately adjacent to each other. If we do this, viewing simply becomes uncomfortable<sup>1</sup>.

In this case, we see what may be some of the first problem. As previously mentioned, in the Python example, `None`, `someFunc`, `SomeClass`, `1`, `0` and `0b101` are all shown in what looks like the same color. It's possible that this isn't really a parsing problem--maybe it's assigning a unique color to each, and they just happen to be so similar that we can't distinguish them.

The old color scheme also differentiates between the class name and the function name, where the new one seems to use the same color for both. Given that they're both syntactically identifiers, it's open to argument that this doesn't affect accuracy (as such), but it seems pretty clear to me that the old scheme is providing more useful information.

In the dark mode pictures, we see at least a few clear-cut cases of excessive contrast. The most obvious are the parameters (`param1` and `param2`) shown in bright white against a deep-black background. In this case, we've pretty clearly gone beyond the level of contrast that most people can look at comfortably. As an aside, there are a few cases where it's a bit more reasonable to break or at least bend this rule a bit. For example, if you're coloring something with a very small area (e.g., a period or comma) you can often get away with a bit higher contrast than if the area were larger.

At least in my opinion, the light mode version of the new coloring fares at least somewhat better in this respect. We still have `None` colored to match the identifiers and literals, and mismatching `if`. On the other hand, the background in this case is a light grey, and the parameter names are in a somewhat darker grey, so the contrast range is considerably more manageable.

Given a wide audience, we'd also like the color schemes to work well for people with color impaired vision. The most common color vision impairment is called Deuteranomaly. If we run the pictures through a filter, we can see a simulation of approximately how these would look. For example, here's the light-mode Python code with simulated deuteranomaly vision:

[image]

Here we see that in the new color scheme, the comment is only *barely* distinguishable from the preceding code, and even less so from the literals (e.g., `'gre\'ater'`) It might not not so close that I'd consider it a clear failure in this regard, but it's enough to make me at least a little uncomfortable (and at least with respect to serving people with color vision deficiencies, pretty close to an outright failure).

The old color scheme is clearly superior in this regard--although contrast is certainly reduced in some cases, everything that started out as a separate color remains quite easily distinct.

There are, of course, other forms of color vision deficiency, up to and including truly complete color blindness. Fortunately, that's pretty rare. Deuteranomaly is the most common, and dealing well with it will frequently also work out well for most of the other somewhat less common cases (e.g., Protanomaly, Tritanomaly, etc.)

Unfortunately, it's fairly difficult to do automated testing of when colors have enough contrast for the difference to be easily visible. There are computations for "delta E" to tell you how much difference there is between two colors, but eyes are easily deceived, so (for example) the surroundings can make two areas with identical colors look obviously different, or areas with different colors difficult to distinguish. About the best we can hope for in a case like this (retrofitting to a system, affecting far too many pages to review each individually) is to get rid of obvious problems.

---

1. Now rarely relevant, but back in the days of CRTs you could get away with more in this regard, because individual pixels tended to have some degree of gradient at the edges, so even the brightest white against the darkest black still had at least some degree of gradient from one to the other. That's *much* less true with LCDs though, so we have to be more careful as the technology no longer covers for our mistakes.

Comment: Looking beyond the individual colors in isolation, however, we see far too high of contrast. The bright white of the variable names on the dark background is literally painful. The Haloween orange used for the function name also contrasts much too strongly with the aforementioned putrid green.

Comment: The new color scheme is also problematic from a functional viewpoint. For example, it appears to use the same color for the name of the class, the function, the numeric literals, and the None (in the Python example). Some of it doesn't even may sense syntactically--for example, in Python both `if` and `None` are keywords, but the new colorizer has given them different colors.

Comment: Oh, and just in case the subject should arise: yes, I calibrate my monitors on a regular basis, and I keep the background lighting dim enough to assure that my eyes are adjusted almost exclusively to the white point of the monitors, not the room (though it's at a fairly reasonable approximation of the standard D55 illuminant in any case).

Comment: I prefer the old colors, because they look like Visual Studio. The new colors feel really weird (especially the green strings, which I always associate to comments).

Comment: I disagree that the new scheme is at all garish, though obviously that is a subjective consideration, and they'll never keep *everyone* happy with *any* change (or no change!) in that area. As mentioned by @Métoule though, green for string literals could be an issue given several very common tools use green for comments. I like that you are keeping comments grey though. In any case I find *what* is highlighted and the contrast levels far more important than the specific colours, I quickly get used to new colour schemes as long as I can see the key things I find helpful to see identified.

Comment: Having sucessfully ranted against a design change - the specific issues probably should be in the questions, especially things like "Some of it doesn't even may sense syntactically--for example, in Python both if and None are keywords, but the new colorizer has given them different colors." One finds things like insipid and garish are often a matter of personal taste though

Comment: @Métoule the IDEs I use have green for strings, grey for comments.

Comment: Thank you for creating the side-by-side before/after shots. I didn't consciously create them in any certain manner other than "I took the old shots at the same time and the new shots at the same time". I'll pass your feedback on the color scheme to the designer. I do see your point about some colors being potentially mismatched or not matching other IDEs. I'll do a bit of cross referencing and see if we can't make some tweaks there for a quick win.

Comment: Side note: I found the info in your comments to be very helpful. I'd recommend adding it to your post to help flesh out the statement/request a bit more and to help deter drive-by downvotes for "personal taste" vs "specific issues"

Comment: Re Python specifically, `None` and `if` are both keywords, but they have different semantic roles: `if` is control structure, `None` is a constant. Highlighting them in different colors is common in IDEs and I actually think it's better that way.

Comment: @zwol: I can see at least *some* merit to that line of thinking. My personal preference would be to start from a high level and make things more or less hierarchical, so (for example) key words are in shades of green and values in shades of blue.In this case, I can see where it would make sense for `None` to be more or less a teal color to accurately reflect that it's a keyword that's typically used in a value context, so to speak.

Comment: In IDLE, repl.it (online IDE), and PyCharm, `if` and `None` are the same color by default.

Comment: If the old colour scheme is better, as it seems to me that it is, is it possible to create a "theme" for the new highlighter to match the old highlighter's colour scheme?

Answer (score 59):

I'd like to say that I appreciate this post.

It is clear, very informative, very detailled, and to me shows that person's concern for the community.

Of course, there will always be different opinion on the result ("I prefer the former highlighting" "I prefer the new one!") but that is inevitable.

I find the reasons to change (and the choice) compelling enough, and the resulting highliting is pleasing to the eye.

(I see some concerns about having several things showing up with the same color: this is inevitable. The highlighting is there to have successive part in a different color, thus making transitions visible, and the overall structure appear, and not to have everything with its own specific color)

Thank you, @ben-kelly, for the information

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I'm glad the post resonated with you. If have any specific concerns about certain items looking funny (either overall or with a specific language), I'm happy to field those as well

Comment: @BenKelly: thank you! And about corrections: I'll let others much better than me answer that (and I personnally find it fine so far. And it is probably good to keep things as 'default/vanilla' as possible for now until it is validated and fully stress-tested, unless some glaring problem is pointed out)

Comment: @BenKelly: I'd just advise (it's probably done): test with several different persons having several type of 'color vision deficiencies', as it is a common problem and this affects a lot of people (some webpages or charts rely only on color to convey some informations, and they are not useable by all). Whenever possible other means (graphics, signs, italics, etc) help as well (for syntax coloring, there is not much option, but contrast or thickness may help to help differentiate some colors. I'm quite sure the devs of the .js took this into account: it may even explain their color choices?)

Comment: Believe it or not, we did actually do some testing with Chrome's new-ish [Emulate vision deficiencies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/03/devtools#vision-deficiencies) tool. You can see some of my comments (w/ pics) on the public [Stacks PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/490#issuecomment-672913795). Obviously, emulation is not perfect, but definitely better than not checking at all.

Comment: @BenKelly: Good to know!

Answer (score 30):

Current maintainer of Highlight.js here, though I'd add a few quick comments.

> highlight.js tends to not highlight punctuation, which makes it a bit less colorful than other highlighters. This is considered a feature. Not a deal breaker by any means, but something I should mention regardless.

This is something I'm open to improving if someone wants to work on PRs and figure out a good way to go about handling this (work with existing themes, not be invasive, etc). https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2500

> I assure you that Mathematica Stack Exchange will be supported at launch. Due to the large size of the mma language definitions, the language is actually split out from the rest.

Some languages MIGHT also be possible to Highlight with a wildcard vs a list of EVERY keyword under the sun... I'm not sure if Mathematica would be one such language or not.  Some of our languages are quite heavy because the keyword approach was just simpler (and more accurate).  That said just breaking out the files and loading them (as needed) is probably the best solution for some of the less popular languages.  And would also help with auto-detect speed.

> For example, looking at the Python example, if is in one color, and None in a different color (which appears to be the same color for 0, 1, and 0b101 and for someFunc and SomeClass). if and None are both keywords,

We've always highlighted literals and keywords differently.  For Python `False`, `None`, and `True` are currently defined as literals.

> the first 5 inline comments are not parsed as comments at all.

Definitely a bug (and should be an easy fix), a GitHub issue would be appreciated. :-)

> Language auto-detection for assembly language seems to be broken.

Auto-detect is on a "best effort" basis... the smaller the snippet the worse the auto-detect, but some languages are also much harder to auto-detect than others.  If you really think there is an OBVIOUS issue (a huge snippet that is constantly flagged incorrectly, etc) then a GitHub issue would be more than welcome...

> Different flavours of assembly language use different comment characters, so this is a somewhat thorny problem.

Indeed, and why have multiple assembly grammars, not just a single one.  I have no idea if it would be possible to have a single grammar for exactly this reason.

Comment: Off topic comment: the links to your GH profile on [this page](https://highlightjs.org/) are broken, they point to https://github.com/yyyc514 which does not exist. Can you please fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure I can update the website itself (I'll ask - it's still managed by the original author), but I've updated the CHANGES.md file on GitHub and it'll be correct in future releases notes.  

Also added a placeholder/pointer profile so no one should get too lost in the future.

Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Nice trick, @Josh. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshGoebel Thanks so much for checking in! Really excited to be using highlight.js. I've written a couple of projects against it and I can say that I'm really digging it for the most part. Looking forward to giving back to the project as well soon. Once I can find the time, I have a few suggestions / PRs to file against it ;)

Comment: @JoshGoebel I think a fair few SO users would like to see the colouring match that of the usual IDE for whatever language. Currently on SO, it does not (e.g. strings in green instead of purple for C# and VB.NET). Is the colouring due to highlight.js or due to customisation by SO?

Comment: @AndrewMorton In general SO controls the colors with their custom theme.  I imagine the goal is for it to mostly look consistent across the platform - not for each language to have an entirely custom look.  That's my understanding.

Answer (score 28):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

### `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` hint doesn't seem to work anymore

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/377214) has a `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` hint at the top of the post to prevent all the code blocks in it from being highlighted. I tried changing `lang-none` to `none` and it still didn't work. (As you say in your post, Prettify identifiers will still continue to work even after the change.)

We were told at the time of the CommonMark migration that `<!-- language-all: [language] -->` hints [would continue to be supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1166971_348754), unlike the `<!-- language: [language] -->` syntax which was being deprecated.

This issue seems to be specific to the `lang-none` and `none` hints as part of this style of HTML comment; other ones seem to be working fine. As an example, this post contains such a comment to indicate C as the highlighting language, and the below snippet is highlighted in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
```

(To test, I also changed the comment to indicate Python and it highlighted the above as Python.)

It seems to work for individual code blocks, using the code fence notation (i.e. ```` ```none ```` and ```` ```lang-none ````):

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

In summary: `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` and `<!-- language-all: none -->` don't seem to work to disable syntax highlighting for a particular post.

Comment: @BenKelly One week later, what came of the review?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to respond to this one. This is currently working *identically* to other sites where highlight.js is not turned on yet. For instance, try on Stack Overflow (just the preview, don't need to post!). `language-all` only works on blocks that do **not** have an override language set, such as via the code fence string or by a regular `language` comment.

Comment: @BenKelly FYI our equivalent of none language wise is "plaintext" and CSS wise is `no-highlight'.  Of course you're free to handle it on the SO side also and simply do nothing.

Comment: @JoshGoebel Yup! I added an alias from `none` to `plaintext`. Easy fix to bridge the gap there

Answer (score 22):

### C is not supported

**There is no C syntax highlighter in highlight.js**. highlight.js uses the C++ highlighter for C, and it is a **nightmare**. It actually makes code **harder** to read than not having any highlighting. I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64124454/918959) on Stack Overflow wherein the same two tokens `struct List`  are coloured in **3** different ways:

[image]

Yes, I've checked that `lang-c` is in use.

I presume there is some logic that detects that the clause starting with `struct List` is a declaration  and then colours the entire line brown:

```c
struct List *newnode = (struct List *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct List));
```

But this is not helpful in any way, and if you actually used a `typedef` `List`, then it would be coloured differently:

```c
List *newnode = (struct List *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct List));
```

**Every other** C language highlighter I have seen colours *token classes*, context-free. For example the token `struct`, a keyword, should always have the same colour.

(Though, since in `struct X`, `X` is a *tag*, it could be distinguished from `X` that is a `typedef`, or a variable or function name)

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2146): splitting C and C++ should happen (and C++ also needs to be drastically improved). As with pretty much all language-level improvements of the highlighter, this is “help wanted”, i.e. probably won’t happen without somebody submitting a pull request.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Why would SO not want this fixed? Or do you mean it's help wanted from the lib's perspective?

Comment: @RobGrant Help wanted from the lib’s perspective. Of course SO would want this fixed, but I’m not seeing them devote any development resources towards highlight.js at the moment.

Comment: Thanks; makes sense. I would definitely say that if SO are using this lib instead of writing their own highlighter, it's on them to add this support if they want their syntax highlighting to work.

Comment: Actually I’ve submitted a new issue for this specific bug, since none of the existing issues directly address it: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2736 — As a further explanation, highlight.js does not try to be context free (and, contrary to your assertion, Antti, nor do *many* other widespread highlighters). In particular, it attempts to recognise declarations of functions and classes/structs, and highlight them separately. This improves readability, it’s just hard to get right. Currently it merely looks for the presence of a `struct` keyword, which is insufficient.

Comment: @KonradRudolph most of those that do, also *parse* the source code and colour according to the AST not just tokens. In **C++** especially it is **impossible** to get right without parsing the *entire source code*. `int a(x)` is a function declaration if `x` is a type, it is a variable declaration with a constructor call if `x` is an object, and you know this only by processing all the includes.

Comment: @Antti I’m [well](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2716) [aware](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2736#issuecomment-704095952) of the impossibility of tokenising C++ code. But, contrary to what you’ve said, many modern syntax highlighters try to assign meaning to tokens *without* parsing. GitHub’s syntax highlighter and VS Code’s (parse-less mode), in particular, fundamentally have the same issue; they do a slightly better job but they still get it wrong (see second link).

Comment: Anyway, splitting the C and C++ tokenisers would allow us to get at least C 100% right, and [I’m working on it](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2736#issuecomment-704177223).

Answer (score 20):

Thanks for doing this! I'm happy about this outcome, as I was a [major proponent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please) of switching to highlight.js back in 2016.

### Great! …but what changed?

To satisfy my own curiosity, I'm wondering if you have an explanation or theory for what changed between 2016 and now to make the switch feasible. [Oded's performance analysis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please/279361#279361) seemed to raise some major issues, and your post indicates they are no longer issues, but I don't see an explanation for why things changed. For example:

Size in 2016:

> It is [too big] … an extra **5kb** minimum for millions and millions of requests a day … This size concern only grows with adding more languages.

Size now:

> … an extra **~17kB** (over the wire) after including all the languages we support across the network. This extra weight gain **was acceptable to us as a tradeoff** for what we were getting in return.

Speed in 2016:

> … (don't forget - we have a highly nested DOM, and many "benchmarks" are done on a very simple page - which is not indicative of performance on Stack Overflow). … In my tests, CPU time for highlight.js was anything between two and four times higher than for prettify … I have also tested by using console.time around our highlighting calls - highlight.js **consistently performed worse than prettify**.

Speed now:

> In our internal performance benchmarks highlight.js **scored better than Prettify consistently** …

Is this size difference acceptable now because of changes in browsers/networks/CDNs, or just because different people were making the decision? Surely the number of requests per day has only increased since 2016?

Do you have information about what performance tests Oded ran in 2016 and why your results now are so different? Is the internal performance testing infrastructure new?
Have there been underlying technical changes to the "highly nested DOM" to make highlighting more efficient? Or have there been significant performance improvements in highlight.js itself?

Again, I'm glad the change was made now — I'd just like to know if there was a legitimate reason to wait 4 years and what changed in that time. Was there something we could have done differently to encourage adoption sooner?

Comment: Well, for one thing, version 10 was released, which users EC2015, which is not supported by IE. However, as SE has long retired IE support (and removed all IE-specific code last year), that's not an issue.

Comment: What also happened is Yaakov. I've managed to get some low-hanging fruit Prettify FR past him in January and that might have triggered him enough to realize they were on a dead-end. We're blessed with him as Community Advocate.

Comment: I assume a very large factor was the matter of prettify not being available as a "modern" package and no longer being maintained. That has a major impact on the maintainability of the application that's not directly obvious. The caching infra also changed between 2016 and now and four years are quite enough time for an OSS team to improve performance...

Comment: I've seen this post and have not forgotten about it. I'm touching base with our Architecture team to draft up a satisfying answer since they are the ones that made the final decision on the changes, given the benchmarks and size delta.

Comment: @rene Don't entirely think that was responsible. My later post in June about Prettify being discontinued by Google wasn't responsible either, in my opinion, as it originally alluded to creating a new home-grown SE syntax highlighter, which probably resulted in that post being internally demoted. I think the real trigger was Ham Vocke's post on CommonMark, on which someone had asked if syntax highlighting would be changed, to which Ham's response was "we'll think about it once CommonMark is fully rolled out", and I think it was placed on their internal radar at that time.

Comment: Main thing that changed is that Prettify has been discontinued. If that had been the case when I was going through my analysis, it would certainly not have been a choice and I would have had to evaluate a few different options. I trust @BenKelly made the right call here, and I am certain the architecture team assisted with that to ensure minimal impact. Fact is - a discontinued library is something that has to be replaced.

Answer (score 18):

### What to do if highlight.js supports a language but Stack Exchange doesn't?

There's an entire [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), and so Mathematica syntax highlight is clearly very important to us. But when I did some digging to find the highlight.js bundle that SE [seems to be serving](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/highlightjs-loader.en.js), Mathematica isn't in the `registerLanguage("...", ...)` blocks, even though it *is* in the set of aliases that StackExchange seems to be defining, i.e. this line is in the bundle

```js
StackExchange.highlightjs=function(){var e={..."mma":"mathematica",...} ...}
```

It's vaguely annoying to be forgotten by the company to whose platform we've contributed so much, of course, but it'd be way more annoying for our nice syntax highlighting to disappear all of a sudden. We've been getting by with custom support for Google Prettify as written by [one of our mods](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/including-google-code-prettify-language-extension-for-mathematica-into-this-site?rq=1). The lack of Mathematica support is extra confusing when we consider that [*highlight.js already supports it*](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/mathematica.js).

So...what's the protocol for adding highlighting for a language that Stack Exchange, the company, need do nothing extra to support, since highlight.js already has it.

#### Sample Code

For reference, the following block is fenced with `lang-mathematica` as the spec. As of when I write this, it renders un-highlighted.

```mathematica
pot =
  Evaluate@With[
     {
      n = 4,
      l = 1,
      c = .25,
      s = .075,
      scale = 4,
      broad = 5
      },
     scale*(JacobiP[n, l, l, #/broad] + .2 JacobiP[2, l, l, #/broad])*
       PDF[
        MixtureDistribution[
         {1, 1},
         {
          NormalDistribution[-c, s],
          NormalDistribution[c, s]
          }
         ], 
        #/broad
        ] - PDF[NormalDistribution[0, .35], #](*+(#/broad)^2*)
     ] &
(* Out: *)
-1.1398350868612364/E^(4.081632653061225*#1^2) + 4*(2.659615202676218/E^(88.8888888888889*(-0.25 + #1/5)^2) + 
    2.659615202676218/E^(88.8888888888889*(0.25 + #1/5)^2))*(5 + 0.2*(3 + (15*(-1 + #1/5))/2 + (15*(-1 + #1/5)^2)/4) + 
    35*(-1 + #1/5) + 70*(-1 + #1/5)^2 + (105*(-1 + #1/5)^3)/2 + (105*(-1 + #1/5)^4)/8) &
```

Comment: I would say it is a bug that it's not included. I don't understand highlight.js enough myself, but for some reason the MMA language JS file is in a separate additional-langs folder (by itself) that doesn't seem to get included when the file is built out. It seems like it is *supposed* to be included, especially given it is listed in the keywords.

Comment: Excellent question. I assure you that Mathematica Stack Exchange will be supported at launch. Due to the large size of the mma language definitions, the language is actually split out from the rest. We do this *currently* with Prettify as well (check the network logs for `lang-mma.min.js`). I've already ensured this bundle has been created and works on my local machine. Thanks for checking in on this, I appreciate the concern and understand any potential anxiety around the matter.

Comment: Some extra comments here for "fun": I did actually attempt to add mma support to the main bundle, but it added `31.1k` *after* gzipping! That means a 75% bundle size increase for a single language. Unfortunately, that wasn't going to fly, so we're continuing to serve it to Mathematica.SE as a separate js file.

Comment: I personally definitely think that's fair enough and I'm glad to hear that it'll work on our site! Do you have a rough idea of what you _would_ be happy with to add it to the main bundle? Our old highlighting makes use of a trie to save as many bytes as possible and I wonder if it would be worth spending the time lowering the impact of the highlight.js implementation. (Also, just a note that MMA adds symbols regularly that need highlighting, so having a regular update schedule would be really great)

Comment: Would it be possible to lazily load definitions for "exotic" languages? I.e. at least for fenced code blocks that explicitly specify a language. That way, at least "power users" can get highlighting for their "exotic" languages, without putting a serious burden on everybody else?

Comment: @Max It's definitely technically possible... SO would have to write some small amount of custom JS to handle things like that... Highlight.js is designed so that grammar modules can be loaded/fetched stand-alone.... so it's definitely possible for a *single* page of Stack Overflow to load an obscure language just to highlight a single snippet - if SO made that possible.

Answer (score 18):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

#### Will the default code markdown be changed to code fences?

Currently if you click the code (`{}`) icon in the editor, then the selected text is still indented (or unindented) by 4 white spaces.

[image]

As the indent method's way of defining a language for a specific code block (`<!-- language: python -->` for example) is deprecated¹, then shouldn't the default functionality of the button be to wrap the code in a code fence (```) instead?

[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/397219)

> <sup>The former method of specifying a highlighting language can still be used for HTML code blocks: place an HTML comment `<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->` before the `<pre><code>` tags and it will work.</sup>
>
> <sup>Also, this former method hasn't been completely removed for four-space indented code blocks, but merely deprecated. While it will still work for the time being on four-space indented code blocks, it may/will be removed in the future.</sup>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the report! At this time, no changes were made to the editor itself or how you write markdown.

Comment: @BenKelly appreciate that no changes have been made, I'm more specifically asking if they will be, due to the deprecation of the related features (specifically the old language specification). Thanks.

Comment: I would say that changes to the current markdown editor are unlikely, considering we have a "new editor" on the public roadmap. I can confirm that fences are the default there. Stay tuned for more updates on the matter.

Comment: Great, thanks @BenKelly that answers the question (answer?). :)

Comment: Same for Stack Snippets.

Comment: I feel like Ben Kelly should deliver all announcements from now on.

Comment: My preference is always to use the code fence (`\`\`\``) followed by the language I want to use (or 'none'). For instance, in Swift I do `\`\`\`swift<newline>my code<newline>\`\`\`` whereas for C#, I do `\`\`\`chsarp<newline>my code<newline>\`\`\`` and if I want to show output that doesn't have formatting, I use `\`\`\`none<newline>my code<newline>\`\`\`` because leaving it blank would use inference based on the question and tags.  It would be good in the new editor to let us specify it there too since so many don't know you can even do this, letting you mix code in a single post.

Comment: It's been almost two years. Could I possibly see any evidence of progress on this new editor?

Answer (score 16):

Apparently `asm` / `assembly` has never(?) been supported as a syntax-highlighting language, and the somewhat decent highlighting we got in the past was from auto-detection (presumably as some other language with `#` or `;` comment characters.)

**highlight.js auto-detection happens to produce way worse results for assembly than whatever prettify.js did, so in practice there is a real regression here.**

Assembly language really doesn't need much highlighting to be readable; it's already syntactically simple and has a regular line format.  But it does benefit *significantly* from fading comments into a colour that stands out less than the rest of the code.

The rest of this answer was written without realizing asm wasn't (ever?) supported; the highlight.js languages including `x86asm` are *not* enabled on Stack Overflow / SE, so of course using them doesn't help.

---

**Language auto-detection for assembly language seems to be broken**.  For example, note the lack of highlighting in the question on [Printing an integer as a string with AT&T syntax, with Linux system calls instead of printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835456/printing-an-integer-as-a-string-with-att-syntax-with-linux-system-calls-instea).  After editing my answer to use ```lang-assembly on the main code block, that block has highlighting but the others don't.  (And does actually look decent.)

**Separately, syntax highlighting for NASM** (a different asm syntax that uses `;` as the comment character) **is (was?) broken**.  In [Unexpected result of subtracting a NASM macro in an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150945/unexpected-result-of-subtracting-a-nasm-macro-in-an-expression/38151853#38151853), ```lang-nasm or lang-assembly leads to a mess that's arguably worse than nothing, because of single-quote used as English punctuation in a comment.  Same result with `<!-- language: lang-assembly -->`.

(Update: no longer as bad as a couple weeks ago. An apostrophe in comments seems to only affect the end of the contracted word, not the entire rest of the block.  But this NASM syntax is block is still not very usefully highlighted, e.g. comments aren't grayed, and only the `0` in `0x..` is in red.  At least it's not clearly or much worse than nothing.  `x86asm` is listed in the [supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) and highlight.js's x86 asm highlighter is supposed to be for NASM syntax.  `x86asm` results in no highlighting; I had to use `lang-x86asm` to get the current highlighting.)

```x86asm
section .rodata           ; groups read-only together inside the .text section
    msg: db "Thank you"
    var: db 0x34, 0x33, 0x32, 0x31   ; dd 0x31323334  ; Since you're passing these bytes to write(2), writing them separately is probably less confusing.  (x86 is little-endian, so they will come out "backwards")

    ;; apparently you want to include var as part of the message, for some reason
    msglen equ $ - msg    ; $ is the current position
```

Previously, this meta answer wasn't getting any syntax highlighting; that's changed now.

---

SO asm answers tend to be more heavily commented than you'd do in real life, because the target audience is people that *don't* understand the basics of asm.  And SO code blocks are more cramped horizontally than a normal text editor so it encourages leaving comments closer to the end of the code, making it worse if they're visually harder to ignore.  (Especially in some poorly formatted beginner questions and answers where comments are ragged and literally no space is left after instructions.)

---

Different flavours of assembly language use different comment characters, so this is a somewhat thorny problem.  Some use `#` to decorate numeric literals (e.g. ARM), so treating `;`, `#`, and `@` as comment characters won't always work.

**As discussed in comments, highlight.js has highlighters for a few different asm syntaxes, no generic asm.**

By looking at tags like `[arm]` as well as `[assembly]`, Stack Overflow should (in theory) be able to pick the right asm syntax highlighting.

For cases like explicit `lang-asm` overrides in the markdown (which isn't explicit enough: doesn't say which flavour), Stack Overflow could (in theory) still auto-detect which syntax to highlight for based on the ISA tag.  e.g. for a post with `[c] [x86]` tags, a `lang-asm` block could still pick x86 highlighting.

Except that doesn't disambiguate MASM vs. NASM vs. `[gnu-assembler]` syntax, with GAS using a different comment character (`#`) than most other x86 assemblers (`;`).  Many questions aren't tagged with a specific assembler syntax name, just x86.  (Most non-x86 ISAs only have one syntax in wide usage; this is mostly an x86 problem.)

To make matters more complicated GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` still uses GAS directive and comment character, same as when GAS is in AT&T syntax mode.  So `[att]` syntax questions aren't the only ones where `#` is the right comment character, even if we could rely on all questions that happen to use AT&T syntax being tagged `[att]`.

But unless / until that happens, I guess we should be tagging asm blocks with one of:

- `lang-x86asm`
- `lang-armasm` (I guess this is Keil's ARMASM for directive syntax, not GAS?  Instruction syntax is the same between both, though.)
- `lang-avrasm`

I haven't dug into how Stack Overflow dispatches anything to those internally supported highlight.js things.

Comment: *"SO asm answers tend to be more heavily commented than you'd do in real life..."* I see you haven't read much of my real-world assembly code. :-) To be fair, I do often write for a person who doesn't understand the basics, since that person is often me 6-8 months later.

Comment: Actually, on my system your example code *is* highlighted, but this highlighting doesn't make any sense at all. See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnEJb.png): the hex literals aren't recognized; even if I change them to Intel-style `34h`, the `h` is still black. The words like `to`, `of`, `for`, `is` are blue, which also makes no sense for assembly.

Comment: @Ruslan: yeah, it looks that way for me now, but didn't before.  (Now matching what I see on SO if I add `<!-- language: lang-asm -->` to the linked answer in the edit box, which I haven't saved because the highlighting is still worse than nothing for that answer).  Perhaps changed when P.Mort. saved an edit, or silently changed rendering at some point without re-saving the question.  Clearly highlight.js is being worked on.

Comment: FYI: Highlight.js has no generic "assembly" grammar.  We currently have ARM asm, AVR asm, MIPS asm, and x86 asm.  So for best results SO would have to include all of these (or whichever is popular) or someone would have to create a 3rd party generic "assembly" grammar and SO would have to use that for code tagged "assembly".

Comment: @JoshGoebel: All questions tagged `[assembly]` *should* also be tagged with an ISA, as per assembly tag-usage guidelines.  I already edit asm question that are missing such a tag to add it.  (The question volume is low enough to keep up with and see literally every asm question.)  A few are tagged with multiple ISAs, for questions about the ARM equivalent of some x86 thing, for example.

Comment: @JoshGoebel: But for x86 specifically, there are many different syntaxes.  Even using different comment characters (gnu-assembler for x86 using `#` vs. almost everything else using `;`) and separately AT&T vs Intel.  (GAS .intel_syntax still uses `#` as a comment character).  Questions are often not tagged `gnu-assembler` or `att` even if they happen to use that syntax.  There are also some syntaxes like goasm that are somewhat different.  I don't know how significant some of those differences are for syntax highlighting.  But for non-x86, tags should disambiguate nicely.

Comment: Ah our x86 seems to be NASM syntax, or at least that's what the comment says. https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/x86asm.js

@PeterCordes I don't know what you mean with all the talk of tagging... I was just clarifying that Highlight.js does not have a single "asm" or "assembly" grammar... so that label doesn't mean anything unless SO chooses to alias is to one of our individual grammars - which I'm not sure is a great idea.

Comment: @JoshGoebel: That was referring to how Stack Overflow uses it, not upstream highlight.js.  When there's no specific language override for highlighting, Stack Overflow detects languages via tags on the question.  By looking at tags like `[arm]` as well as `[assembly]`, Stack Overflow should (in theory) be able to pick the right asm syntax highlighting.  For cases like explicit `lang-asm` overrides in the markdown (which isn't explicit enough: doesn't say which flavour), Stack Overflow could (in theory) auto-detect which syntax to highlight for.

Comment: Oh. I had no idea that it could use tags. Most of the discussion that I’ve read is just about markdown overrides   Yes, SO could map one alias to multiple auto-detects if they wanted to. Or do neat things with multi-tag. I’m not sure they actually have written any of that logic though. Stack overflow may not be loading those asm grammars at all though I’m not sure.

Comment: I dont think anything is broken here. It just isn't supported by SE. Check the list of supported languages linked to in the "Question".

Comment: @Luuklag: asm syntax highlighting used to at least sort of work before the change, I think.  I don't have a clear memory (or screenshot) of exactly how any specific code blocks looked before the change, except that comments did used to get grayed out.  When I posted this, asm syntax highlighting had gotten *vastly* worse, to the point of being much worse than nothing.  It's improved some in the past week or two, but still doesn't gray out comments as well or as reliably.

Comment: @PeterCordes you might want to check the list of supported languages, and try out a few by explicitly setting the highlighting languages for a codeblock. If you end up with a reasonable result with a certain language selected that would make more sense as a FR. It could also be that other tags on the question influence the selected language, so then it might be helpful to force highlighting to `default`.

Comment: @Luuklag: I checked https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md linked from the question, as you suggested.  `lang-x86asm` is the same as what I'd already been getting for the block in this answer.  Auto-selection is by far not the only problem.  Even overriding to the correct asm syntax (x86asm is supposed to be NASM) gives a pretty messy results for the NASM syntax in this answer.  I don't have enough interest in syntax highlighting to sort this out, just to report it the major regression from how asm syntax highlighting used to work on SO.

Comment: @PeterCordes that language is not supported by SE. They only support the languages in the other link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109. So this is no bug, but a feature request to add a certain language to the highlighter.

Comment: @Luuklag: Wait a minute, so `lang-asm` / `lang-assembly` has never been supported on SO?  And it just happened to get auto-detection based on syntax and do something which turned out to be useful in most cases with prettify.js, unlike with highlight.js?  I guess in hindsight it was probably treating GAS code like some other language with  `#` comments.  Anyway, in practice it's still a regression in practical results, however we want to classify it and maybe do something about it in the future.  At least that explains why x86 NASM syntax highlighting isn't working.

Comment: Yes, it never was supported. It would either get highlighted as `default` or something else based on the other tags of the question.

Comment: Assembly code was always randomly coloured on StackOverflow.  No one seemed to care though. Despite another answer saying no colour is better than wrong colour most people just seem to want pretty colours.  The current everything is green syntax highlighting that assembly usually gets I suppose is technically better, but doesn't give people the pretty colours they want, or provide any useful syntax highlighting.

Comment: @PeterCordes It would be super interesting if someone had a way to find out which Prettify grammar was actually being used in the past if that seemed to work so well... SE could always choose to force assembly to any grammar they wanted that provided good highlighting results (if they choose not to build in the explicit assembler grammars).

Comment: @JoshGoebel: Highlight.js seems to do ok with `lang-bash` for GNU assembler (`#` comment character, and a line-oriented language).  e.g. I gave it a try for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64679979) which was once again a disaster by default.  Agreed it would be interesting to have a look at exactly what the old system was doing; I remember `lang-assembly` not working perfectly but usually being fairly reasonable.  But I don't remember any of the details of random words that would get highlighted differently from others that I could use to guess a language.  There were some, though. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes I think long-term SE will load more grammars dynamically... (which is the real solution here)... but if not they should probably consider some tiny custom grammars... if all you MOSTLY care about is comments that's only a tiny amount  code to make a grammar that would just only highlight comments, and leave everything else alone with 0 false positives.

Comment: @JoshGoebel: As I pointed out in my answer, different assembly languages have different comments characters (and some use `#` as part of the syntax for numeric literals in some contexts), but yes a couple different simple grammars for different comment chars could work.  And yes, doing nothing but comments would be totally fine and vastly better than nothing; good asm style already makes most other things visually easy.  A few refinements could include a color for `label:` labels.  Some other easy things I can think of would be anti-helpful in badly-formatted asm (like insns not indented).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes of course I certainly didn't mean a SINGLE grammar... although if two assemblers shared the same comment syntax and you were purposely being that minimal then you could indeed reuse the grammar, but you'd need one grammar per ruleset of course. Still it'd be ridiculously small.  And yes labels would be nice and easy.

Comment: @JoshGoebel: Right, so then the problem becomes naming the different grammars.  Do we want something like `asm-hashcomment`?  That seems bad and not something anyone would ever guess, and not future-proof if more specific new grammars *did* get added.  So I guess we'd want something future-proof like `asm-gas` or `asm-att` or `assembly-att` / `asm-mips` / etc. (GNU assembler for x86, MIPS, etc.) mapping to one grammar vs. `asm-nasm` / `asm-masm` / `asm-yasm` / `asm-fasm` / etc (Intel-syntax with `;` comments) all mapping to another grammar.  And `asm-arm` for `@` comments.

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." :-)  I'm not sure why the names would change... name them whatever you've always named them... If there was no pattern before your suggestion doesn't seem awful. :-)

Comment: @JoshGoebel: I (and probably others) had been using `lang-asm` or `lang-assembly` in the rare cases where it highlighted wrong from auto-detection (based on tags and/or content), since that gave the appearance of working.  So yes, we would need to invent a naming convention.

Comment: Assembly might be easier to classify than others though so IF you truly kept it as simple as just comments and labels then perhaps it wouldn't be that hard for a simple classifier to figure out which comment style was being used.

Comment: I've started an effort to add x86asm as a supported highlight language on SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412543/support-x86asm-as-a-highlighted-language.

Answer (score 12):

I've just tried the following piece of JavaScript code (from [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210369/58563) in Code Golf) because Google Prettify was not parsing the regular expression followed by an inline comment correctly. That's why I used alternate slash characters in the original post (I've turned them back into regular slash characters below).

But this is much worse now, as the first 5 inline comments are not parsed as comments at all.

```javascript
f = (                // f is a recursive function taking:
  [c,                //   c   = next digit character
      ...a],         //   a[] = array of remaining digits
  o = '',            //   o   = output string
  S = new Set        //   S   = set of solutions
) =>                 //
  c ?                // if c is defined:
    f(               //   do a recursive call:
      a,             //     pass a[]
      o + c,         //     append c to o
      o ?            //     if o is non-empty:
        f(           //       do another recursive call
          a,         //         pass a[]
          o + [, c], //         append a comma followed by c to o
          S          //         pass S
        )            //       end of recursive call (returns S)
      :              //     else:
        S            //       just pass S as the 3rd argument
    )                //   end of recursive call (returns S)
  :                  // else:
    S.add(           //   add to the set S:
      o.replace(     //     the string o with ...
        /\d+/g,      //       ... all numeric strings
        n => +n      //       coerced to integers to remove leading zeros
                     //       (and coerced back to strings)
      )              //     end of replace()
    )                //   end of add() (returns S)
```

I'm sure this is going to be fixed quickly, so here's a picture of the current rendering for later reference. :-)

[image: rendering]

Comment: This looks like a bug upstream in the language processor itself. The first few comments are getting marked as being included in the params of the function. I'd recommend filing a bug or submitting a PR against highlight.js itself

Comment: @BenKelly At any rate, there are probably a couple of good test cases on Code Golf as you'll find there plenty of unusual (yet valid) ways of writing and commenting code, at least for the few standard languages that are actually recognized by highlight.js. (We obviously don't use syntax highlighting at all for all the esolangs we're using.)

Comment: @Arnauld I made a PR for this and also fixed a long standing Scala issue that was similar while I was at it.  Thanks.  Will make it into the next minor release.

Comment: @JoshGoebel Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: This should be resolved in 10.3 (just released).

Answer (score 12):

In LaTeX code, `@` should be treated as a letter. There are any number of examples on tex.stackexchange, but

*[Undefined control sequence on \beamer@leftmargin indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505192/undefined-control-sequence-on-beamerleftmargin-indentation/505348#505348)*

```latex
\begin{frame}[fragile]{E}
\makeatletter
\hskip-\beamer@leftmargin
\makeatother
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
```

`\beamer@leftmargin` is a single token, but `beamer` is coloured and `@leftmargin` is left as unstyled text which makes the code very hard to read.

Technically, @ is not always a letter, but it is almost always a letter when appearing in code sections and is a far better default in a syntax highlighter.

Comment: This seems like something you should file to the [Highlight.js repository](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues).

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog I could, although I wasn't sure if stackexchange were collecting things up here and then reporting upstream rather than a million stackexchange users suddenly swamping the highlight.js repo with individual bug reports...

Comment: Major thanks for the much improved LaTeX support in 10.3.0 (ground up rewrite) contributed by @schtandard.  I just released 10.3.0.

Answer (score 11):

There has been times that I've turned off code highlighting with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` because Prettify was getting it wrong, and no highlighting is better than wrong highlighting. (The example that comes to mind was a Bash snippet where `#` wasn't a comment indicator, but Prettify thought it was.) After this change goes through, should I go back over those posts and turn code highlighting on again? Is it better?

I suppose I can test it.

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend simply adding the language any time you consciously think about it. If you use the code fence syntax (my personal preference) you can easily set the language. That being said, give it a shot! I have a [sibling post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401031) on Meta Stack Overflow that explains how autohighlighting is changed (at 5000 ft anyways).

Comment: @BenKelly you think it's OK to force us to manually set the lang on each of 10 code snippets in a question, say? even then, it's erratic, works for some snippets, doesn't work for others. examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Comment: This was marked as bash, @BenKelly, but Prettify didn't pick it up. I'll try to find the post again now, and edit it. Can't remember where it was.

Comment: Yup. It works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6482403/209139

Comment: @WillNess I think right now there is some confusion about which languages SO actually supports (with the new Highlight.js support).  You can find a complete list on the post where they talk about how highlighting works. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

If a language isn't listed there no amount of proper tagging it will help. Some people are confused because Highlight.js supports a particular language but SO do not.

Comment: @JoshGoebel in e.g. pastebin.com it just works. in SO, it doesn't. I'll let the paid stuff worry about the rest. :)

Comment: @WillNess Single purpose sites are always simpler. :-)  If SO fixes their core implementation a bit and then people pitch in to report remaining issues I imagine things can improve greatly. I don't think going back to Prettify is an option, so unless they want to switch to something else or roll their own the best outcome for all is to improve Highlight.js and fix any obvious bugs. :-)

Are you super familiar with Prettify?  When I took a look (at the original code) it just looked to be a very simple pattern matcher/highlighter... is that all there is to it?

Comment: @JoshGoebel pastebin supports lots of languages too; how good, I have no idea. but e.g. Haskell looks super nice there. SO could just use what they are using, and if that's in-house, just buy the thing. no, I know absolutely nothing about implementing this thing. (on a completely tangential note, what are the chances for someone (me) to see a new, somewhat unusual/remarkable surname for the first time in their life, ***twice*** in one day! I do mean yours and someone from 1980s named Randy Goebel whom I saw mentioned today in connection with "Waterloo Prolog".... what *are* the chances!!? :) )

Comment: (.... by pure chance, I mean).  what a coincidence, huh!?

Comment: @WillNess pastebin.com is server-side looks like... I imagine it was very important for SO to let the clients do the heavy work of highlighting vs doing it on their own servers... and for simple (small footprint) JS based highlighting the two big players I know of are Highlight.js and Prism.  I assume they would have also considered Prism, though I'd be curious to know what led them to choose us over Prism.  (we do try and be a bit more ambitious than Prism in our highlighting)

Answer (score 10):

We have been [waiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284072/create-verilog-syntax-highlighter) for Verilog and SystemVerilog (SV) highlighting for a long time. Apparently we will have Verilog support with *highlight.js*, but SV will continue to be unsupported. Still much better than before. I'm happy with the change and appreciate your effort.

Let me put some Verilog code (from [highlight.js demo](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/)) here to see the result after the roll-out. I assume the language code will be `lang-verilog`.

EDIT: We haven't got Verilog support as Ben Kelly mentioned in the comments. The following snippet has no language code, thus we see the result of auto detection.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

/**
 * counter: a generic clearable up-counter
 */

module counter
    #(parameter WIDTH=64, NAME="world")
    (
        input clk,
        input ce,
        input arst_n,
        output reg [WIDTH-1:0] q
    );
    
    string name = "counter";
    localparam val0 = 12'ha1f;
    localparam val1 = 12'h1fa;
    localparam val2 = 12'hfa1;

    // some child
    clock_buffer #(WIDTH) buffer_inst (
      .clk(clk),
      .ce(ce),
      .reset(arst_n)
    );

    // Simple gated up-counter with async clear

    always @(posedge clk or negedge arst_n) begin
        if (arst_n == 1'b0) begin
            q <= {WIDTH {1'b0}};
            end
        else begin
            q <= q;
            if (ce == 1'b1) begin
                q <= q + 1;
            end
        end
    end

    function int add_one(int x);
      return x + 1;
    endfunction : add_one

`ifdef SIMULATION
initial $display("Hello %s", NAME);
`endif
endmodule : counter

class my_data extends uvm_data;
  int x, y;

  function add_one();
    x++;
    y++;
  endfunction : add_one
endclass : my_data
```

Comment: Hurrah. About ....ing time.

Comment: If you want SV support, I suggest [consulting the highlightjs dev documentation](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-guide.html) and creating a pull request. I’m in the process of doing this for multiple languages.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but this update has not added any new language support (officially. Technically sublanguages like `Less/scss` got snuck in with the css support). I tested this code snippet on my dev environment and it autodetects as `scala`. That being said, adding more languages to our bundle is technically trivial, but we need to be mindful of bloating the deliverable size. I'll keep this suggestion in mind once we revisit and decide whether to add additional language support.

Comment: @BenKelly Thanks for information. I removed the language code, but there is no highlighting for scala either.

Comment: @BenKelly To avoid bloated bundles, could new synxaxes not be loaded dynamically depending on what's present on the page? (I'm holding out hope for `\`\`\`diff` and `\`\`\`elixir` support...)

Comment: @LionelRowe In theory, yes. That being said, I've not looking into the possibilities there or how it would impact us (from a bandwidth/hosting perspective) or our users (from a UX/performance perspective). This is definitely something we'll keep in mind if we decide to expand our supported languages in the future.

Comment: I suppose we've been collectively waiting 7 years, whats a few more. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @TomCarpenter You must be referring to [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198364/enable-verilog-syntax-highlighting). We have 15 days to the 7th anniversary. :)

Comment: @BenKelly If performance is a concern, perhaps maintain two separate files: `highlightjs-compact` (contains only core languages, e.g. C++, Java, Python ...) and `highlightjs-all` (contains a larger selection of languages, including Kotlin, Fortran, SystemVerilog, ...).

Comment: @BenKelly There is an issue open for "dynamic loading" of languages on the Highlight.js GitHub, but it's not a huge priority right now.  Someone has a plugin also, but I wouldn't call it "solid" yet... (not sure it's the proper way to go about this)

The best way to do this is likely to "wrap" HLJS (or at least `highlightBlock`)... if the language is valid (but not bundled and not loaded yet), issue a `fetch`... and then on competition just call `highlightBlock` again in the promise success callback.

While loading you'd apply the `hljs` class (so the blocks appear as unhighlighted code).

Comment: I had a demo/prototype of something like this working for our codebase, but the problem isn't just the size of the bundle, but it's about number of network requests too. Adding even a *single* extra request to our most hit page on our most hit site (Question view on SO) would be murder on our CDN bill. Not insurmountable by any means, but it just needs extra thought/engineering at our scale. We wanted to get the base out first and make sure it works well before we really started messing with the process.

Comment: @BenKelly Someone mentioned a web worker for local caching... of course the same kind of thing would also be possible with just fetch/localStorage or something... Language grammars should be 100% frozen between patch releases (which should greatly simply their caching)... so once you cached say "10.3.1/obscure_lang.js'  on a given client  it would never need to be fetched again until your version of Highlight.js was bumped, invalidating the "10.3.1" cache key...

To lower the number of total requests you could have a "secondary pack" that loaded multiple languages.

Answer (score 10):

### Will lazy loading of syntaxes be supported?

This would allow for syntax highlighting of less common languages that don't need to be eager-loaded on every page load.

Here's a proof-of-concept that doubles as a [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) user-script:

> [Highlight.js lazy-loading proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/lionel-rowe/0e8a86296e340f6c4d54ddd51a30ed02)

Naturally it's a little hacky, but it works on all of the following examples:

#### ```` ```lang-diff ````

```diff
- print('failure')
+ print('success')
```

#### ```` ```lang-elixir ````

```elixir
spawn_link(fn ->
  send(current_process, {:msg, "hello world"})
end)
  
receive do
  {:msg, contents} -> IO.puts(contents)
end
```

#### ```` ```lang-bf ````

```bf
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
```

Comment: Does it work on CSS? The Google Prettify highlighter has always had trouble recognizing CSS.

Comment: @user289905 It works only for languages specified with `lang-XXX`. Shouldn't be required for CSS, though, because that's already eager-loaded by default.

Comment: When I run this I just end up with a whole bunch of console warnings and no visible effect: `Could not find the language '_____', did you forget to load/include a language module?`, fill in the blank with `none`, `assembly`, `diff`, `elixir`, and `bf`.

Comment: The concept is surely nice however, I really like the idea of being able to run a script user side that would highlight more languages.

Comment: @zcoop98 Those warnings are generated when hljs does its initial pass, not when the userscript runs. I've amended it to run on the `load` event for the original hljs script (which is itself loaded dynamically), but this still doesn't suppress the warnings. Can you confirm you're seeing no color at all on these code blocks after running the script? It's a little difficult to see at the moment, especially for the Elixir example, due to the hljs color scheme.

Comment: @LionelRowe I can see colors now!

Comment: Fixed to work with the latest update - the eagerly loaded run now highlights unknown but specified languages with what I assume is a best-guess attempt? Anyway, v0.4 of the user-script will now override these.

Comment: @LionelRowe This is awesome.  Don't think you can suppress the warnings since you probably have no way to load and change anything BEFORE Highlight.js makes it's first pass... but they aren't really causing any harm either.

Comment: @LionelRowe Why is MutationObserver necessary?

Comment: @JoshGoebel At least when I made this, the hljs script was not present at the time `DOMContentLoaded` was fired, necessitating the `MutationObserver`. I left the 3 conditions at the bottom in case the means of loading was changed.

Comment: @LionelRowe Here is a proof of concept Chrome extension: https://github.com/joshgoebel/se_highlightjs :-)  Nice thing about an extension is you can bundle the files, no need for any CDN or external fetches at all.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Visual Basic code is no longer highlighted

The error in the console is:

```
Could not find the language 'vb', did you forget to load/include a language module?
Falling back to no-highlight mode for this block. <pre class="lang-vb s-code-block">
```

Comment: Seems VBA, VB.Net and VBScript all affected, even though all 3 are uniquely supported in highlight.js (unlike prettify, where I thing VBA just mapped to one of the other two)

Comment: Interestingly `vbs`, `vb`, `vbnet` as tags for code fences all result in some kind of default highlighting that some gibberish tag `dfbdfkbk` also produces, as if they aren't recognised - however `vba` suppresses highlighting altogether, so slightly different

Comment: Thanks for the report. I may have missed a language alias here. I'll double check and get the changes into my first round of fixes going out today.

Comment: `vb` and `vbs` now will set the language to `vbscript`. I had _somehow_ missed aliases for literally just these two languages `:facepalm:`. Must be some sort of repression mechanism from the first half of my career writing primarily in VB.Net ;). `vbnet` and `vba` (not being supported aliases) will result in the code autohighlighting instead.

Comment: @BenKelly Thank you. However, the current highlight does not look like VB to me at all :(

Comment: @GSerg Do you have an example post you're looking at that I can use to reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: @BenKelly Anything, really? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64017640/11683. The type declarations (`As String`) should be blue, including the `As`. String literals should not be green. `True` and `False` should be blue.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for the update. The `As` not getting highlighted is a shortcoming of highlight.js's language definitions for vbscript. As for the colors, what item should be what color is left to the theme. Part of the highlight.js rollout was a new theme, which might be causing the confusion

Comment: @BenKelly That is not surprising really because vbscript does not have `As` in the first place. It also does not have [other things](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/VBScript/Content/html/90bf1300-fb5c-42b5-9051-b5338b67a8dc.htm), which I assume will then also not be highlighted. Arguably, out of the VBA, VB.NET and VBScript, the latter is the least good candidate for representing the other two. It is certainly a step back for all three then :(

Comment: @GSerg I've taken your comments into consideration and I've decided to switch the syntax highlighter from `vbscript` to `vbnet` instead. There's no specific reason it was `vbscript` to start, just that's what I chose. In hindsight, `vbnet` is the obvious choice. Thanks for bringing this up! The change should go live sometime tomorrow.

Comment: @BenKelly One consideration after looking at the highlight files for the different languages (vbscript, vba, vbnet) is the latter two contain "illegal" attributes such as `'//|{|}|endif|gosub|variant|wend|^\\$ ', /* reserved deprecated keywords */` in vbnet. I believe these illegal attributes only affect default highlighting by telling the language recogniser to bail early if it finds `wend` -  since that couldn't possibly match Vb.Net - but of course `wend` is valid in VBA/VbScript. IIUC SO tags override default, so will matter? Some valid VBA is never auto-detected essentially

Comment: Basically what I mean is, if SO relies on highlight.js auto-detection, then using vbnet (or vba) to highlight all the vb family, will result in some false negatives, eg. where code is valid in VBA but not VB.Net. VBScript is the most lenient in syntax, because it has the least of it (and thus does a poor job highlighting VBA and VB.Net, but a good job detecting them). If SO doesn't need autodetection much then this is a non issue and the most keyword rich `vbnet` is certainly superior as a catch-all (ofc all 3 individual highlighters would be most optimal)

Comment: @Greedo Can you tell me in what contexts VBScript (vs VBA or VB.net) is still alive and being used today?

Answer (score 8):

### Will the `<!-- language: [language] -->` hint be disappearing?

Back when SE was switching to CommonMark, we were told that [the old `<!-- language: [language] -->` syntax had been deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1167297_348803) and was subject to removal in the future. (Prior to the implementation of code fences, this was the proper syntax to force a single block of code to be highlighted differently from the rest of the post.) With this change, will that comment style be removed once this is rolled out to all the sites?

It seems to work fine at the moment. The following is specified as a C code block:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
```

...and here's the same text, but as a Python code block:

```python
#include <stdio.h>
```

Are there plans to remove it, or will it remain for the foreseeable future? If it is going to be removed, will it still be that posts rendered prior to its removal will still honor it until they're edited, [as we were told at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1167515_348803)?

Comment: At this moment, there is no plan to completely remove support for the language comment syntax. If this were to change, we'd make an announcement on meta first. As much as I am not a fan of the syntax, we don't have a good replacement for `language-all` in commonmark *or* our supported extended syntax. I've not changed anything in the implementation for the highlightjs switch, so any issues are to be considered bugs. (I see the one you reported above, thanks for reporting!)

Comment: @BenKelly To be clear, `language-all` would continue to be supported; only `language` had been deprecated. As you say, there isn't a good replacement for `language-all`, but code fence hints exist as the preferred alternative to `language` today.

Comment: I should have specified: There is at this time no plan to completely remove either `language` or `language-all`. One or both could possibly be removed in the future (with `language` potentially going first since there's a real, widely accepted alternative). If we do decide to do this in the future, then we'll broadcast the change ahead of time in order to gather feedback from the community.

Comment: @BenKelly I just read further into that post, and it seems like the plan wasn't to remove `language` entirely, but to remove its support *only* for four-space indent code blocks and retain it for HTML `<pre><code>` blocks. I think that may be too technically difficult to implement, so I think the best solution would be to retain it as is. (It seems to me that Ham intended to remove it entirely at that time, but ran into issues with it, so he simply marked it as "deprecated, subject to removal" instead.)

Answer (score 8):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

PowerShell and batch syntax highlighting is off all around and neither works correctly 
*(left: Stack Exchange; right: Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code))* 
[image: Screenshot1]

- It appears batch and PowerShell syntax have been linked to each other, which simply doesn't work for either due to the different ways variables and other characters are used between the two:

  - PowerShell comments use `#`, whereas batch uses `::`  [image: Screenshot 2]
  - PowerShell variables use `$`, whereas batch uses `%<variable>%` 
     [image: Screenshot3]
  - PowerShell doesn't support linking commands via `&`||`&&`, using `;` instead, which batch doesn't support
- PowerShell syntax only syntax highlights if first letter of command or parameter is capitalized, leading to a ridiculous amount of posts not syntax highlighted unless edited, as it doesn't syntax highlight if the entire command/parameter is in all lowercase or all uppercase *(latter also affecting batch)*, which it should since PowerShell isn't case aware

  - PowerShell and batch syntax highlights don't apply as they should when code fences are used *(also an issue with other languages)*, regardless whether the syntax is specified after the code fence or not - the only way to reliably have it syntax highlighted is to use HTML syntax comment `<!-- language-all: lang-powershell -->` or `lang-bat` *(it was also an issue with Prettify)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1525/discussion-on-answer-by-jw0914-goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-o).

Comment: [Feature request: Please bring a version of highlight.js which supports PowerShell onto StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355370/1968)

Answer (score 7):

### SQL Formatting issues

As I almost exclusively stick to SQL Server related tags, I've picked up on a few issues/features with the sql language formatting.

#### Hash character incorrectly interpreted as comment character in SQL

In the below example, on the first line, everything after the `#` in `VIN#` is a coloured as a comment. On the third line, everyting after the `#` in `#TempTable` is. This doesn't, however, occur within the literal string, does within brackets (`[]`) (used by T-SQL as a delimit identifier), and doesn't within double quotes (`"`) (the ANSI SQL delimit identifier).

```sql
SELECT VIN#, NTT.fID, GETDATE(),
       SYSDATETIME()
FROM #TempTable TT
     JOIN dbo.NonTempTable NTT ON TT.ID = NTT.fID
WHERE Description = 'Hello#there' AND NTT.Val = 3
  AND [VIN#] > 7
   OR "VIN#" < -12;
--This is an actual single line comment
/* 
This is a
Multiline
Comment
*/
```

`#` isn't even a comment character in SQL. Single line comments are defined with `--` and multiple with `/* ... */`.

This is actually quite a problem, especially when temporary objects start with a `#`, and are used frequently with DDL and DML examples.

---

Further edit

#### Brackets (`[]`) not treated as delimit identifier

In T-SQL (as stated above) Brackets (`[]`) are the default delimit identifier, rather that double quotes (`"`), which are the ANSI delimit Identifier.

If a key work is within brackets, it is highlighted incorrectly. For example:

```sql
SELECT [name]
FROM dbo.[Table] T
     JOIN dbo."VIEW" V ON T.ID = V.IDl
```

I did decide to check, and there isn't a T-SQL variant option:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM dbo.[Table] T
     JOIN dbo."VIEW" V ON T.ID = V.IDl
```

---

Another edit:

#### The @ character isn't recognised as a variable identifier

Variable names aren't highlighted, or "immune" to other highlighting. Variable names are prefixed with an `@` in SQL. For example:

```sql
DECLARE @variable varchar(10),
        @Table table (ID int),
        @Date datetime2(0),
        @1 int,
        @NonReservedWord sysname;
```

Notice that all the variable names, apart from `NonReservedWord`, receive incorrect syntax highlighting.

Comment: Highlight.js "SQL" language is intended to be very "baseline".  It's not going to handle every possible SQL variant well. Currently it includes too much (and on the list to be scaled back)... if someone wants "better/proper" MS SQL support then the correct solution is for someone to provide a 3rd party grammar module for MS SQL variant.

Currently we already have PostgreSQL (core) and Transact-SQL (3rd party) grammars in addition to the plain jain "SQL".

Comment: @JoshGoebel that doesn't explain most of the above. Yes the brackets (`[]`) are T-SQL specific, however, `#` is a very different story, as only `--` and `/*...*/` are the ANSI methods for comments. `@` is also the common theme for variables. The majority of this is not T-SQL specific. The misinterpretation of `#` as a comment is especially detrimental in my opinion.

Comment: Re:Comments.  This is because there yet exists no "MySQL" SQL grammar so that support has been squeezed into SQL... MySQL does indeed allow # comments.  What needs to happen here is for someone to creates a separate MySQL grammar and then the SQL grammar can be simplified (removing # comments).

Does ANSI SQL even have variables?  Variables would be something pretty trivial to add to the existing SQL support (since it currently includes too much).  I'd be open to a PR against SQL adding variables.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516642/2029983) from 2014, it does (did) not, @JoshGoebel . Though, not all of the languages use `@`. For example T-SQL (SQL Server), MySQL use `@`, where asPL\SQL (Oracle) and pgSQL (PostGreSQL) do not. SQLite doesn't actually support Variables at all; by the looks of it. I do admit that all the RDBMS using (vastly) varying implementations of SQL does pose many problem from the perspective of a generic "SQL" language implementation.

Comment: I will add variable support to SQL since that will prevent false keywords also. https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/2740/commits/9c04ffe48bd04106e5bb87cd4fb03f6347eb948c

Comment: Sadly the SQL grammar improvements didn't make it into 10.3 because it turns out we're going with a complete rewrite of the SQL grammar.  The new grammar should hopefully do much better overall on snippets but will drop vendor-specific (non-standard) things like MySQL comments.  We could still use any contributors who might want to create (and help maintain) 3rd party modules for MySQL and Oracle to support the nuances of those vendor's SQL grammars.

Comment: Thanks for the update @JoshGoebel, appreciate it.

Comment: I'd be happy to help out with Oracle SQL and PL/SQL, if Oracle Corp can't spare anyone :)

Comment: SQL improvements finally landed in 10.5 for a holiday release! SE just updated to 10.4.1 so I'm not sure when the next update will be. CC @BenKelly

Answer (score 7):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) <sup>*(Manually changing this from `bug` to `status-bydesign` given my discoveries documented below.)*</sup>

I searched around, but I couldn't find any previous posts referencing [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). 
Regular expressions are stated to be [currently supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/776523), but it *is not* in the [list of languages supported](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) by highlight.js (it *was* supported by Prettify).

There are some weird effects when highlighting complex expressions, e.g., from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/11047824):

```regex
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

It sometimes italicizes the characters between asterisks `*`, and other times fails to highlight character lists inside square brackets, `[]`.

If it's not supported by highlight.js, <strike>where is this highlighting scheme even coming from?</strike><sup>*See update*</sup> Are regular expressions included in the FAQ list by mistake<sup>1</sup>? I notice that the default highlighter for the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag on SO is `lang-default` rather than `lang-regex`.

---

#### Update

So I've done a little digging, and it appears what's really going on here is that the regular expression in this post is getting *auto-recognized* as Markdown, even when specified as `regex`.

Setting the identifier of the same snippet as `lang-markdown` has an identical effect as `regex`:

```markdown
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

This leads into the discovery I made, which largely revolves around the last sentence of my original post:

> I notice that the default highlighter for the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag on SO is `lang-default` rather than `lang-regex`.

As described in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402170/11047824) by [@T.J.Crowder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/134069/t-j-crowder), and backed up by the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), **there is a difference between identifying a code block as `lang-X` vs. just `X`**.

As per the help center (emphasis mine):

> You can use either [one of the supported language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), like `lang-cpp` or `lang-sql`, or **you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used**.

This was news to me! I had been under the impression, which I'm sure many others are as well, that ID `X` was simply a shortcut to `lang-X`. This is incorrect.

Therefore, ID'ing a snippet as `regex` is really saying "identify this snippet as the defined identifier for [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)". This happens to be `lang-default`, which is really a shortcut to tell the highlighter to "guess" what the correct highlight should be, which in this specific case, becomes Markdown.

So it's going `regex` ==> `lang-default` ==> `lang-markdown`.

Popping open the console to take a look at the first snippet here will still show `class="lang-regex s-code-block hljs"`, even though it's getting highlighted as Markdown. I believe this is due to how highlight.js works. It appears it never actually changes the identifier class name itself, but rather injects the child syntax classes underneath it in regardless.

---

<sup>1</sup> - It looks like it was added back into the list in the FAQ post on Sept. 28 ([Rev. 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/184109/100)), and given my discoveries below, the answer is *yes*, it is a mistake.

Comment: @BenKelly  I really wonder if you should not blocklist some tags completely from highlighting.  There is NO good guess for highlighting regex... you shouldn't even try. **The result is guaranteed to be poor.** This probably also applies to some other more unique languages also, like brainfuck, etc...

Answer (score 6):

Does highlight.js support emphasis in blocks formatted as "code" (ie indented 4 spaces)?

Paraphrasing [an MSE question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371782/lets-fork-google-prettify-library):

In-code highlighting (anything will do), would be a great way to emphasise the important parts.

Currently, the best people can do is ASCII art arrows, eg:

```
printf("%5s", "foo")
         ^--- add a width value
```

which happens often enough and is probably not done more because it's a pain and ugly.

It would be great to be able to highlight (in this case) the `5` by making it red, bold, or whatever by surrounding it with some special chars, maybe like `!5!`  or whatever works.

Awesome would be highlighting with a comment that *isn't* selected when copy-pasting the code block.

---

I'm putting my hand up to donate my time and coonsiderable software engineering skills to make this happen. Let me know when you have a github repo up, you've added me as a contributor, and you have a task management system up (eg Trello, please not jira!)

Comment: There's nothing like this in highlight.js proper that I'm aware of. Technically, we could support `diff` highlighting, but that brings its own set of drawbacks. highlight.js *does* support plugins, so this could be something that we could potentially write a plugin for. This is not currently on our radar as far as I know, but it is definitely something to think about for the future.

Comment: It wouldn't help in the code block situation since the HTML tag would be displayed rather than treated as a tag, but it would be nice if `<mark>` were a supported HTML tag on StackExchange so that relevant potions of text could be highlighted.

Comment: @ben something that both amazes and saddens me is SO not tapping into the 1000’s of top class developers that would willingly donate their time (they already do) to writing code to deliver features. For some a reason I can’t fathom, SO is dev is a closed shop. In this particular case, surely there are 100’s of devs that are members of this community who could write such a plugin. Why not just ask them to do it, and it would get done pronto.

Comment: @M.Justin yes, there must be a way. If we write a plugin, we can pick what we like. Eg `<mark comment="some comment that is visible, but not selected when copying code">some.code()</mark>`

Comment: `<pre><code>` blocks can include arbitrary HTML (IF the editor permits AND they're using the traditional `highlightBlock`)... so you could just wrap it in `<span class='highlight'>my code</span>` and assuming there was a highlight class the HTML is preserved and will be "passed thru" while the code is highlighted... so when finished that `span` will still be in place.  Requires a CSS class though.  Long-term a solution like `<mark>` via some sort of plugin would probably be better though.

Answer (score 6):

#### Syntax highlighting isn't always present in the entire code block

This is an odd one. I've noticed this in a few languages, not just SQL, but sometimes the highlighting just doesn't work on the entire code block. This *appears* to happen more when the code snippet isn't complete on its own (and so isn't valid syntax on its own).

Take the below SQL snippet for example:

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN SIPCOD in ('001','500') or (SIPCOD = '013' and SISHCD = 'OTA')
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN SIPCOD in ('501','502') and SIHRS >= 3.0
         THEN 0.5
         ELSE 0
    END) as [Days Worked]
```

Even with the language defined (both with `sql` or `lang-sql`), the first line to receive syntax highlighting is the fourth line (`END) -`); the prior lines have no highlighting. The image below is from SO Dark Theme:

[image]

I'll try and repro this with some other languages and edit it in, or if I see other examples (I'm sure I've seen at least one C# and PowerShell example over the weekend on my mobile).

This is SQL again. However, this one doesn't highlight the last line, for some reason:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [135.282.123.12].tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] = N'##Tmp1')
    PRINT N'YES';
ELSE
    PRINT N'No';
```

[image]

---

Apologies, this is SQL again, but the highlighting is all kinds of wrong in this code block. It starts, then suddenly stops, and then picks up again it the oddest place:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.RealTable (ID int IDENTITY);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
--Good attempt
EXEC dbo.CreateNewColumn @TableName = N'RealTable',
                         @ColumnName = N'SomeString',
                         @sql_dtype = N'nvarchar',
                         @length = '255',
                         @SQL = @SQL OUTPUT;

PRINT @SQL;
--Another good attempt
EXEC dbo.CreateNewColumn @TableName = N'RealTable',
                         @ColumnName = N'SomeInt',
                         @sql_dtype = N'int',
                         @SQL = @SQL OUTPUT;

PRINT @SQL;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
--A bad attempt
EXEC dbo.CreateNewColumn @TableName = N'RealTable',
                         @ColumnName = N'AChar',
                         @sql_dtype = N'char',
                         @length = N'CREATE USER test WITHOUT LOGIN',
                         @SQL = @SQL OUTPUT;

PRINT @SQL;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
--Bad parameters
EXEC dbo.CreateNewColumn @TableName = N'RealTable',
                         @ColumnName = N'SomeNumeric',
                         @sql_dtype = N'decimal',
                         @length = 7, --This should be precision and scale
                         @SQL = @SQL OUTPUT;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
--Good parameters
EXEC dbo.CreateNewColumn @TableName = N'RealTable',
                         @ColumnName = N'SomeNumeric',
                         @sql_dtype = N'numeric',
                         @Precision = 7, --This should be precision and scale
                         @Scale = 2,
                         @SQL = @SQL OUTPUT;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.RealTable;
GO
DROP PROC dbo.CreateNewColumn
DROP TABLE dbo.RealTable
```

Comment: Here's one for JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497499/2415524

Comment: Quotes containing multiple keywords seem to confuse it. Possibly the same issue as mine - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354944/394486

Comment: That’s “by design”: the current SQL definition explicitly only attempts to correctly highlight complete SQL chunks. There’s arguably no good reason for this — it’s a debatable design decision. The same design decision causes the issue observed by @WilliamRobertson.

Comment: That's *possibly* ok on sites that include complete code solutions like [codereview.se], @KonradRudolph , however, Stack Overflow code blocks often don't include full code solutions, as they don't need to. Enforcing code blocks to be a complete, and valid, rather than a snippet is a huge detriment to the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Larnu I obviously agree. My comment is *explaining*, not defending, the behaviour.

Comment: Fair enough, @KonradRudolph, I may have misinterpreted the intent of your comment.

Comment: Let's be clear "by design" doesn't always mean "intentional".  I'm not sure if there is a reason the SQL syntax was written the way it is, but I'm not opposed to improving it to be  less context aware (which would improve the highlighting of tiny SQL snippets - IF they are flagged as sql).  Small snippets of course are always hard to correctly auto-detect.

Comment: If the syntax highlighting simply "stops" at some point that's likely a deficiency with the grammar ruleset.  IE, it's matching the beginning of a rule and never finding the expected end, which results in the remaining content not being highlighted.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Questions which do not have any tags associated with any languages do not get their code blocks automatically highlighted at all. Examples:

[Preloader is not working on Angular universal SSR app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112840/preloader-is-not-working-on-angular-universal-ssr-app)

[How to Get a List of Members in a Guild Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197222/how-to-get-a-list-of-members-in-a-guild-discord-js)

Note that questions *will* get highlighted if they have at least one tag with a "Highlight Language" in their wiki, *even if that language is `default`* - like with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). Questions with at least one such tag will get their code blocks automatically highlighted. In contrast, a question only with tags like [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/discord.js/info) which has no highlight language (not even `default`) will not have any code blocks highlighted.

I think when no tags have languages associated with them, the question's code blocks should be highlighted automatically. Maybe remove the difference between the association with `default` highlighting and a non-existing language association while you're at it, unless it's needed for something. (Or give *all* tags a `default` language association.)

All questions should at least have something like

```html
<div style="display:none" id="js-codeblock-lang">default</div>
```

but it should never be empty, or auto-highlighting won't work:

```html
<div style="display:none" id="js-codeblock-lang"></div>
```

This issue is pretty similar to a related standalone question: [Improving syntax highlighting language auto-detection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354793).

Answer (score 5):

There is something a bit odd with PL/SQL (or SQL - I'm not sure whether PL/SQL is actually supported. It seems to be sadly unpopular with syntax highlighting plugins.)

A quoted SQL statement seems to defeat the quoting, but only when an earlier line ends with a semicolon.

```sql
select blah into blahblah from blahblahblah;  -- Semicolon here seems to do it

xxx := 'select select';

Quoting is now reversed.
```

Looking at other SQL-related issues, I see [Syntax highlighting isn't always present in the entire code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354674/394486) also has an example where quoting is broken by a quote that includes a SQL keyword.

Screenshot for posterity:

[image: highlight-js glitch with SQL]

The actual post where this came up is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183788/230471

**Edit:**
Marking as Lua seems to work better with quoting:

```lua
select blah into blahblah from blahblahblah;  -- This is a comment

xxx := 'select select';

Quoting is not reversed.
```

Comment: highlight.js doesn’t support PL/SQL, and Stack Overflow in particular only supports SQL, which is a shame, since highlight.js has a separate definition for pgSQL (which includes PL/pgSQL!) that’s of vastly superior quality to the SQL definition.

Comment: We support PL/SQL via PL/pgSQL... if StackOverflow wished to provide that variant, they could.  "SQL" is intended to be very basic (although sadly it's currently got MySQL mixed in with it).  Really the SQL variants are so different that to get the best results you really need to use one specific to the server variant you're using - which is why they should all be broken out into separate grammars.

There are also size concerns (which might be why Stack Overflow just doesn't want to add everything in the kitchen sink)...  I'm definitely open to making our "simple" SQL support better.

Comment: I'm making a small change to SQL that will always match strings (even if outside an apparent SQL statement) that will prevent examples like those above from being totally broken. https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/2740

Comment: I'm guessing the "MySQL mixed" is why only the first declaration after a `declare` keyword is highlighted. In PL/SQL `declare` marks the start of a section containing multiple items and ending with `begin`.

Comment: Since PL/SQL is a wrapper for SQL (among other things) perhaps there is a way to include a common SQL grammar and extend it with begin/end/loop etc for PL/SQL. But then I've never written a JavaScript syntax parser so I have no idea what I'm talking about (though I did extend my [fork of code-prettify](https://github.com/williamrobertson/code-prettify) to [include PL/SQL](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/pretty-print-plsql.html).

Answer (score 5):

Bash highlighting seems to be broken.

```bash
echo "$(true)"
echo $(true)
```

As you can see, the command in the first subshell is not highlighted, presumably due to the quotes, but the second is (no quotes). Both should be highlighted.

Adding a PNG image in case this gets fixed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report! This looks like an upstream issue. The language is getting correctly detected as `bash`, so the issues are due to the highlightjs syntax definitions themselves.

Comment: Correct, currently `$(...)` inside a string is only matched as a "subst" (special code within a string) there is no further recursive processing for subshells... This is something that should be fixable...

Comment: After Ben's message, I looked at highlight.js issues, and it looks like a similar problem was already reported. Highlighting for this specific case helps users to notice mistakes (even if they should try their code before submitting an answer ;)).

Answer (score 4):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

What are we supposed to do if syntax highlighting doesn't turn on *at all*?

In a question with a very simple code block, with only the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, this is what I see:

[image]

For the block of code:

> ```
> MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration( cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
>     .ForMember( k => k.Sector, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver>() ) );
>
> Mapper.Initialize( config );
> ```

The only highlight is on `new` for some reason. The rest of the c# questions have the proper highlighting for me.
If it makes any difference, using latest Firefox on Windows and no console errors.

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  There are no other keywords there to highlight.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I noticed that on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159713/overloading-output-operator-for-a-class-template-in-a-namespace) the syntax highlighting for some C++ code stops partway thru.

In particular, it gets tripped up by this bit of code:

```cpp
template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const skg::Triplet<T>& p_t) ;
void other_stuff_that_isnt_colored();
```

If the operator is changed from `<<` to something else, the coloring continues

```cpp
template <class T>
ostream& operator+(ostream& os, const skg::Triplet<T>& p_t) ;
void other_stuff_that_is_colored();
```

but the color for the `operator` keyword is the identifier color, and not the keyword color.

If the `template <class T>` part is removed the coloring is correct.

```cpp
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const skg::Triplet<T>& p_t) ;
void other_stuff_that_is_colored();
```

Comment: Hadn't noticed this answer when i posted my [third](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354674/397219). Glad to think I wasn't going crazy and had seen this on other languages! :)

Comment: See https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2716

Comment: This is fixed in 10.3.1 I believe.

Answer (score 4):

#### LaTeX highlight in TikZ environments is wrong.

Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564540/38080:

[image]

It seems that a newline in a macro arguments desynchronize the parser...

Thanks!

PS: could be this:https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2709 ...

Comment: The problem is not the newlines, the issue is with the nested braces. After `spacing}*` the highlighter thinks that it is no longer inside an argument and starts outer-level (i.e., orange) highlighting. Compare `\foo{\bar} \foo{{}\bar}`. For another clear example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564420/is-there-a-python-module-for-parsing-latex.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## No Objective-C highlighting

I commented to say how disappointing [highlighting of Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910192/reversegeocodelocation-stored-as-nsstring-producing-error) is, but I was told to open a bug as it is not an issue of Highlight.js, but of Stack Overflow not applying it (it applies C highlighting instead, and with that what I see highlighted makes sense).

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Comment: Thanks for the report! This is actually due to the objective-c language being split out from the c-like languages and the tag still pointing to the old language code. I'll get a fix in for this today. Nice catch!

Comment: This fix is now live. Any post with the `objective-c` tag will now correctly assign the `lang-objectivec` syntax instead of `lang-c`.

Comment: @BenKelly It is better, it now recognises class names and declarations, however it does not highlight methods & properties, so it still looks quite a bit un-highlighted. Could it have a choice of styles perhaps, or is highlight.js just not very good for objective-c?

Comment: Traditionally (as a policy) we have not highlighted method dispatch or properties, but we're now more open to this and welcoming PRs in cases where it's simple enough to detect.  See https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2500  There is work to be done deciding how they should be highlighted, whether we need to add new CSS classes, etc... so if you want to help out or join the discussion (or work on a PR) feel free to do so. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There are two problems with Groovy syntax highlighting:

1. The old syntax was not automatically converted to the new syntax, i.e. thousands of Groovy-related questions and answers lost syntax highlighting.
2. Groovy syntax highlighting via  ```` ```groovy ```` does not work in many cases (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63984970/1082681)), only in some.

For details please read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354555/309898) and its comments.

Comment: Added a comment to [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354555/what-happened-to-groovy-syntax-highlighting/354581#comment1184810_354555). Will mark as status-review here as well

Comment: See response to linked question. Groovy syntax is still not explicitly supported, but it should now at least auto-highlight to whatever similar language highlight.js thinks it might be

Comment: We do have a grammar for Groovy if you're talking about https://groovy-lang.org.  I assume StackOverflow simply isn't loading that yet?

Comment: I know that and also mentioned it in my question. It don't know why SO does not just use something that already exists. I also asked in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354591/309898) how to go about making a feature request to explicitly support Groovy, but received no answer. Slightly off-topic, IMO syntax highlighting in general (also for Java) became worse after switching the highlighting framework. My own answers are way less readable than they were before, fewer elements are highlighted and where they are they don't stand out much, which also affects Groovy indirectly.

Answer (score 3):

**Java highlighting difference**

I don't know what the exact rules was, but in the old highlighting any word in the Java code starting with a capital letter was highlighted.

I found this a nice feature since class names should start with a capital letter, so class names would stand out from variable names in the code.

Of course there was an issue when people didn't follow Java conventions, but overall I found the code easier to read.

In the new highlighting there isn't any difference between capitalized or uncapitalize words, so class names and variables names all appear the same.

Comment: I'd say this is intentional since there is no real difference (only a convention as you said).

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby numeric literals are not highlighted as expected

In Ruby, float, rational, and complex literals render like so:

```ruby
3.5e4
2r
6i
```

The expected behaviour is for the entire literal to be highlighted. For comparison, here are the same float and complex literals with Python highlighting:

```python
3.5e4
6j
```

(Python uses `j` instead of `i` for the imaginary unit and doesn't share Ruby's literal syntax for rationals.)

Is it possibly an upstream issue?

Comment: Python has a `j` suffix for imaginary numbers which is indeed highlighted. Other suffixes are not highlighted, so the Python behavior is definitely correct and the one for Ruby needs to be fixed.

Comment: Ruby's grammar is not aware of these numeric variants, but it could be.  Would be happy if someone created a PR. :-)

Comment: @JoshGoebel I had a look at the grammar (right before you commented, strangely enough). I think maybe I could put something together...

Comment: @Dingus PR is welcome. :)  Lots of other languages to see samples from.

Comment: Created an issue to track this. https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2766

Comment: Merged and will be released when 10.4 comes out.

Answer (score 3):

Display bug in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64104147/750) to a post with [python](/questions/tagged/python) - which should get it Python-like coloring. A string is colored in two different ways:

[image: Two different string colors]

Comment: Well the the snippet isn’t valid Python code and the highlighter assumes it is, and hence highlights it incorrectly (the highlighter has special logic to colour class names, and gets thrown off by the `class` keyword).

Answer (score 3):

Per advice at [How does the highlight.js change affect Stack Overflow specifically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401031), I am copying [my original bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401520/deleted-code-block-rendering-problem-on-recent-update-of-chrome) to this Q&A.

Because I first noticed this behavior coincidental with an update to Chrome, I originally suspected that some change in Chrome might be related, though *not necessarily at fault*. However, I just saw today the news about the change to the code renderer (i.e. this Q&A), and that change also happened at exactly the time that I first noticed this problem.

I now strongly suspect a problem with the highlight.js renderer itself.

### The original bug report below:

---

Browser bug, or site bug?

Chrome just recently updated (to version 85.0.4183.121). After the update, code blocks found in deleted posts are rendered badly:

[image]

Interestingly, if you select the text, it looks okay:

[image]

Chromium-based Edge (version 85.0.564.51) still displays fine:

[image]

<s>Of course, this may not be the case once Microsoft pulls into the Edge code whatever Chromium updated happened to cause this.</s> Microsoft has updated Edge to version 85.0.564.63, and I still do not see this problem with that browser.

The above examples are C# code. I don't have ready access to deleted posts in other language tags, so I don't know whether this occurs for all code formatting or just C#. I'm guessing the former though.

Naturally, this seems most likely to be a browser bug. But it's not unheard of to find that some buggy HTML/CSS works fine in one version of a browser but not another. Hence this bug report.

Edit:

**Additional information:**

On further investigation on my part, I've discovered that this only occurs on some posts, not all. For example, I see the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64038788), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64024829) (oddly, one code block is fine here, while the other is broken), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64038459), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64037988), but not [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64071011).

Interestingly, even on the ones where it does happen, if I click the `edit` link (for example, so I can examine the markdown to see how it might be different), and then cancel the edit, the rendering is now correct, at least until I reload the page.

In every case I looked at, rendering is broken when the author used indentation to denote a code block (with the exception of the mixed-problem one noted above, which uses indentation for both blocks, but only the second renders wrong), while it's fine when the author used back-tick markup.

Also: if I use the touch-screen to change the scale, rendering is fixed immediately, on the first change in scale. However, if I use the menu to adjust the zoom factor, it remains broken until reaching 150% scaling, at which point it renders correctly.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this on the same version of Chrome (macOS), and it’s almost certainly unrelated to highlight.js which, after all, does not touch the way code is displayed at all, so it won’t affect font rendering behaviour. I recommend posting a separate post as this is a serious bug — though probably unrelated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: fact is, this new problem showed up the same day that Stack Overflow switched renderers. In any case, if you read the post above, you'll see that I did already post it as a bug, and it's gotten no response at all from the Stack Exchange team. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: Well it isn’t (it literally *can’t* be!) highlight.js related, so it doesn’t belong here. I missed the link to the original report; that’s the right way to report it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: _"Well it isn’t (it can’t be!) highlight.js related"_ -- unless you have debugged the problem and found out what is actually going on, you cannot possibly make that claim. And the idea that the component that has as its sole purpose to format the code as displayed in the browser _"does not touch the way code is displayed"_ is just plain absurd. That's _all_ it does.

Comment: I mean, sure. There’s a theoretical, absurdly low, probability that it causes that. But you seem to misunderstand what highlight.js does. It simply parses code and produces HTML `<span>` tags which, in turn, are styled using run-of-the-mill CSS (not even the font, *it only sets colours*). But even the CSS isn’t produced by highlight.js, it’s fully controlled by Stack Exchange. Highlight.js simply does not touch the graphical font rendering *at all*. It’s an engine that transforms *strings* into different *strings*. Graphics/rendering do not come into this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: you are overlooking the fact that it really doesn't matter whether the bug is in highlight.js itself, or simply in the way that it's used. It's still a bug related to the change from Prettify to highlight.js. You claim incorrectly that _"it **can't** be highlight.js related"_, which is patently false. It may be true that highlight.js itself cannot directly affect rendering, but to say that the problem can't possibly even be **related** to Stack Exchange's use of highlight.js is naïvely and prejudicially incorrect.

Comment: I'm curious to know who provides the training on how to respond to bug reports.

Answer (score 3):

### More formatting issues with SQL

[hightligh.js has proper support for **PostgreSQL and PL/pgSQL**.](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/)

Still, my code is messed up on a regular basis. Like in this example (I ended up with a workaround using dollar-quoting to keep it readable - which is also not recognized, although it should be):

- [Passing column names into dynamic SQL in stored proc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/276688/3684)

Using `pgsql` as format specifier does not seem to have any effect. Seems like you removed that somehow? Falling back to `sql` is a poor substitute:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_result_table(_param1 integer[], _param2 text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _table_name text := to_char(current_date, '"_XYZABC_"YYYY_MM_DD"_ZXCVBN"');
   _select     text := '(select * from some_other_function($1, $2))';  -- !
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE some_schema.%I AS ', _table_name)
         || _select
    USING _param1, _param2;
   
    RETURN _table_name; 
END
$func$;
```

Can this be fixed?

This is particularly unfortunate as I am currently hard-coding the format specifier `sql`, which should later be `pgsql` once the issue is fixed. Or what's the best workaround for now?

**Update:** I settled with tagging `pgsql` for now. That seems to be ignored, currently. So formatting falls back to the language determined automatically (currently mostly `sql` for Postgres questions, I assume). Once `pgsql` is fixed, the format specifier will kick in correctly.

It will be fixed, eventually, or will it not?

In case you are unfamiliar with dollar-quoting in Postgres:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860)

Comment: I believe that is because SO is only using "SQL".  They really should provide the individual SQL variants (such as PostgrSQL, etc) for best results.  SQL is not intended to highlight ALL SQL variants well.  If anything it's currently focused more on MySQL but long-term it should really be just ANSI SQL with people using the correct variant fo whatever server they are using.

Comment: Is $$ quoting a part of ANSI SQL?

Comment: @JoshGoebel: Dollar quoting is [not part of the SQL standard](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.7.2). It's a (very convenient!) extension of the standard in Postgres.

Comment: I have a PR to improve SQL to be less context dependent so will at least fix the fact that half the bottom of your snippet is detected as a string... Right now the `;` in the middle is tripped it up because it reads that as the end of the statement.

Comment: I believe Josh maintains the highlight.js library. However SE would still need to update the version they are currently using then. This is a notourisly slow process.

Comment: @luuklag There is no reason it needs to be so slow for minor/patch releases.  We'll see if it improves going forward.  A *minor* version bump of Highlight.js should be relatively trivial.  Even if they wanted to allow time to us to find any issues in a new minor release usually that happens within a few days or week... and we do have a large number of tests.  So if stability was a concern a policy of "wait ~1.5 weeks after minor release, then upgrade" should be quite safe. We'll see how it goes.  I just released 10.3.

Comment: @JoshGoebel I didn't imply there are reasons, from hearsay and exoerience it is known that staff takes a while to update these things.

Comment: Well perhaps I shouldn't have said "no reason"... lol... SO is also a pretty huge service, and I'd call code highlighting a "critical feature"... so I'd imagine to some degree a known set of bugs with an existing library is better than unknown bugs in a new release.  So if I was guessing I'd say "system stability" might be a concern that weighs into some of these decisions... perhaps.  Although again minor releases and patch releases should be "pretty safe". :)

Answer (score 2):

**C code in a question tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [cpp](/questions/tagged/cpp) is misdetected as [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown).**

[What?!](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64259836/1)

```markdown
typedef float pnt[3];

void count(pnt const * pnts, const int n, unsigned cnt[8]) {
 
  for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    cnt[i] = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[7]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]< 0.0f ) ++cnt[3]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]< 0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[5]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]< 0.0f && pnts[i][2]< 0.0f ) ++cnt[1]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]< 0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[6]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]< 0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]< 0.0f ) ++cnt[2]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]< 0.0f && pnts[i][1]< 0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[4]; else
    ++cnt[0];
}
```

It renders as

[image]

Comment: Both the C and C++ tag have a highlighter set (lang-c and lang-cpp). When two tags have a highlighter it falls back to lang-default. Add an explicit language hint to each code block.

Comment: @rene Interesting, I didn’t know they would cancel out, that’s definitely not great.

Comment: I didn't know either. I needed Martijn to explain how it worked, See my revisions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401174/578411

Comment: There is also a feature request to supply all the tag-associated languages as hints to highlight.js instead of a fully 'blind' autodetection: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354793/improving-syntax-highlighting-language-auto-detection

Comment: > "When two tags have a highlighter it falls back to lang-default"

This definitely sounds like poor behavior on SE part.  I'll jump into that thread next but both tags can easily be input to the auto-detecting algorithm, ie SE could easily tell us "I KNOW this either is C or C++ code".   And with a small amount of extra effort you could "weight" the highlighter such that "I'm confident, but not entirely sure this is C or C++ code".

Comment: That said this specific case is definitely an issue with our XML grammar being too greedy.  It seems all those `<` as HTML and starts crediting everything it sees as an HTML attribute... which makes no sense because this is so not XML in so so many different ways.  So this specific auto-detect failure is something we could fix upstream.

Comment: Filed as an upstream issue: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2767

Comment: There is a PR to fix this that will be merged soon and will be released when 10.4 is out.  Markdown was also far too "greedy" and claiming anything that looked like [x][y] as a link.  This has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

**C# Stack Trace in Log File Formatting is Wrong**

See [What does "Keyword not supported: 'endpoint'" mean and how does it relate to the "messaging" connectionstring?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26526/what-does-keyword-not-supported-endpoint-mean-and-how-does-it-relate-to-the)

This is a log file that contains a C# stack trace. It doesn't seem to pick up C# as the language and highlights it wrong.

Comment: This is correct behavior. If no language is specified, it has always attempted to highlight with a "default" that covers most language generics. You can always [specify the language manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Actually the "best match" is found and that is used for highlighting.  So if your code "looks like" Python in our [Highlight.js] opinion, they you will get Python highlighting.  As mentioned the best way to always get the correct highlighting is to specify the language manually.

Answer (score -1):

I ran across the following code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251604/using-select-class-with-flask).

You can see the coloring is not formatted properly:

```
<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="title">Numéro</label>
       <input type="number" name="NUMERO"
              placeholder="666, etc" class="form-control" required
              value="{{ request.form['NUMERO'] }}"/>
   </div>
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="TYPE_VOIE">Type voie</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="TYPE_VOIE" required >
          <option>Rue</option>
          <option>Impasse</option>
          <option>Place</option>
          <option>Boulevard</option>
          <option>Avenue</option>
      </select>  value="{{ request.form['TYPE_VOIE'] }}"
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This isn’t a bug, the question is tagged as [tag:flask], so Stack Overflow (reasonably) infers that the code in the question should be Python. I’ve fixed the formatting now by correcting the markup in the question.

Comment: How is this not a bug? It has incorrectly identified the code as Python when it is obviously HTML. The question is also tagged with bootstrap-4. Why would prioritizing the Flask over bootstrap-4 tag be correct?

Comment: Also, Flask is a web framework. Maybe it would be better to narrow down the possible code types to Python, HTML, Javascript, and CSS, instead of assuming all code has to be Python.

Comment: Fair enough I guess (to be clear: I agree that Stack Overflow really *should* be doing this better, it’s embarrassing that the world’s largest (and most flush with cash!) programming QA website can’t even *remotely* get syntax highlighting right, ugh) but the heuristic for detecting languages has *always* worked like this, and the change of highlighting engine didn’t cause this mis-detection.

Comment: Quickly checked the last 3 questions posted with the Flask tag. All 3 of them have code other than Python in the questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252171/how-to-efficiently-load-large-csv-file-into-html-table-using-flask), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251996/flask-api-failing-to-decode-json-data-error-message-failed-to-decode-json), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251604/using-select-class-with-flask))

Comment: Perhaps I decided to pay more attention to the formatting since they made the change.

Comment: @noslenkwah: It is not pure HTML. It is HTML mixed with the Django template language - the `{{ ... }}` part. (It can be anywhere, not just inside a string)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q: It's more likely jinja2 given that the question is about Flask. Regardless it clearly isn't formatted in any useful manner. Formatting as HTML where the small bits of templating language are left unformatted is clearly more useful than how it is currently formatted.