# Could we include the Stack Exchange Highlight.js theme in the Highlight.js core package?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Once the final theme is agreed upon would Stack Exchange be open to submitting a PR to add the theme "officially" to the core project so smaller sites who enjoyed your theme could use it on their own sites, or would that not be something you'd want to do...?

We'd be happy to include it. (I'm the current maintainer of Highlight.js)

**Benefits**

Anyone using Highlight.js could use the theme easily if they enjoyed it.

**Drawbacks?**

Perhaps you don't want to share your "brand" in that way?

---

Context:
[Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter)

Answer (score 11):

**Update May 2021**: A community member was kind enough to create this pull request in GitHub: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/3189. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

I don't see why not! In fact, the theme is already open source (MIT license) as part of our [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) design system. You can find the exact styles [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/blob/develop/lib/css/components/_stacks-code-blocks.less).

After the theme matures a bit and changes settle down after launch, I'll see about creating a PR to add it to highlight.js proper.