# Support more highlight.js language formatters

Tags: feature-request, bug, syntax-highlighting

I'm not quite sure what Prettify was doing before, but now [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) questions seem to be getting highlighted in a pretty random set of choices. For an example, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64192481/1 is a question where the embedded code is now being highlighted entirely wrongly as Typescript and C#, neither of which is even remotely correct in visual appearance (critically in this question, the comments are not being highlighted as such); I “fixed” it by forcing the highlighting language to `bash` but that's wrong (it's a language that has nothing to do with the question) so I don't see it as a “fix” that should be encouraged at all.

Now, I know that highlight.js supports Tcl — I can see a correct example on their demo page — so the failure is definitely not an upstream problem. (The other tag on the question definitely doesn't have a highlighter.)

---

There's got to be many other languages in the “long tail” of questions on this site that suffer from similar problems. I definitely can't list them all. But any sane solution to this needs to be not just for one language not currently on the blessed list; that's just kicking the ball slightly further down the road.

Or if that can't be done, can we at least not have utterly wrong highlighting schemes being applied? *They're actively misleading right now, making it harder to read questions and answers.*

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug or a FR. It's on the fun boundary between the two…

Comment: Probably something very like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354555/what-happened-to-groovy-syntax-highlighting#comment1184805_354555

Comment: TCL is (intentionally?) currently not included in the list of languages SO supports.  It's included in Highlight.js, but they are choosing not to load that grammar - so I imagine you're just seeing auto-detect do a poor job since it's not ever given an opportunity to decide if it might be TCL or not.

Agree: It's definitely worth a discussion on how to prevent highlighting at all for languages that SO purposely chooses not to support rather than just picking some random language and doing a terrible job.  Although I'm not sure how to do that unless SO just block-listed some tags.

Comment: @DonalFellows I wrote a Chrome extension that adds support for every single language Highlight.js supports if that might prove helpful.  It currently only kicks in if those languages are manually hinted ie, *```tcl*, etc., but adding auto-hint support based on question tags is on the list.  So just seeing the post is tagged `tcl` could trigger TCL to be used for highlighting.  I'm hoping some others will contribute.  https://github.com/joshgoebel/se_highlightjs