# Markdown characters in code both shown and rendered as markdown

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

With certain syntax colourings active (for example "apl" but not "c"), and for certain specific characters, symbols that have meaning in markdown are visible while also causing formatting. Examples are

```apl
*II*
```

and

```apl
*1*
```

but not

```apl
*I*
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you saying that some syntax highlighters (like `lang-apl`) are visibly formatting characters that they shouldn't, or are you saying that the Markdown highlighter shouldn't show the symbols that it formats?

Comment: @zcoop98 Neither. I find it hard to believe that the syntax highlighter would italicise specific names and numbers. Rather, it looks that the Markdown processor fails to recognise code blocks when certain languages are in effect, and so we get both markdown effect and syntax highlighting. Not sure why the MarkDown processor wouldn't remove the asterisks, though…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no bugs here; at least, not the bug that you think:

> ...it looks that the Markdown processor fails to [recognize] code blocks when certain languages are in effect, and so we get both [the] markdown effect and syntax highlighting.

A quick peek at this post's source/ HTML markup shows that the appropriate segments have been detected as code blocks: all 3 code blocks' contents have been wrapped properly in `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` tags with the `s-code-block` class applied:

```html
<div class="s-prose js-post-body" itemprop="text" style="display: block;">
   <p>With certain syntax colourings active (for example "apl" but not "c"), and for certain specific characters, symbols that have meaning in markdown are visible while also causing formatting. Examples are</p>
   <pre class="lang-apl s-code-block"> <!-- Specified language and s-code-block classes -->
       <code class="hljs language-markdown"> <!-- The actual class HL.js is using (!!!) -->
           <span class="hljs-emphasis">*II*</span> <!-- HL.js class for this code section -->
        </code>
    </pre>
   <p>and</p>
   <pre class="lang-apl s-code-block">
        <code class="hljs language-markdown">
            <span class="hljs-emphasis">*1*</span>
        </code>
    </pre>
   <p>but not</p>
   <pre class="lang-apl s-code-block">
       <code class="hljs language-css">
           *
           <span class="hljs-selector-tag">I</span>
           *
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

What *is* perplexing, at first glance, is that while the blocks are classified as `lang-apl`, the actual language highlighter the first two are using is `language-markdown` (which explains the italicized Markdown formatting we see):

```html
<pre class="lang-apl s-code-block">
    <code class="hljs language-markdown">
        <span class="hljs-emphasis">*1*</span>
    </code>
</pre>
```

What's actually going on here, however, is revealed by a glance at the console:

[image: Image of console with 3 of the below message visible]

The first notice reads:

> WARN: Could not find the language 'apl', did you forget to load/include a language module?

This tells us that highlight.js doesn't recognize `lang-apl` as a highlighter.
The real insight, though, comes from the next line:

> WARN: Falling back to no-highlight mode for this block.
> `<code class=​"hljs language-markdown">​…​</code>​`

While the error *says* it's falling back to "no-highlight" mode, what's really occurring (the real bug here?) is that the *next best guess* is being used for the block– in this case, that's apparently Markdown.

This also accounts for why the third block *isn't* italicized, since the third error indicates that the highlighter is falling back to `language-css` instead of Markdown, hence the difference.

(One might be inclined to blame the highlighter for this error, but there are really no right answers when trying to guess the language of a 3 to 4 character string.)

#### Takeaways

1. APL isn't actually a language [supported by highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md)
2. Stack Exchange has the highlighter set to use the "next best guess" as a fallback
3. For some snippets, especially tiny ones, this is a *terrible* strategy, which leads to strange and unpredictable results

   - This last bit [has been detailed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355852/stop-guessing-auto-detecting-a-language-when-you-know-it-will-be-incorrect), by a maintainer of the highlight.js library
   - Throw some  support to that feature request if you want this to change! (The language recognition part of highlighting on Stack could be ***so much better***, the current implementation handicaps the library in this department)