# Groovy syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

According to the [list of supported languages for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109), Groovy has been missing for many years, despite the fact that *highlight.js* supports Groovy and Groovy is not a particularly exotic language. Far more exotic ones like Haskell, Erlang, Ocaml etc. are supported, but not a widely used JVM language like Groovy. Using ```` ```java ```` as a replacement for Groovy is just a crutch or a suboptimal workaround, as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354555/309898) previously.

Groovy is used as a stand-alone programming language for projects like Grails, Gradle, Spock, Geb and many more, as a scripting language for Jenkins, Jira and - again - Gradle (each Gradle build file is Groovy code). The list could go on endlessly. It would be a minor effort to support *lang-groovy* and connect important tags like *groovy* to that language syntax highlighter. The benefit would be huge to a big developer community active on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related: [Julia syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368443) ([[meta-tag:status-deferred]], unfortunately)

Comment: The Gradle highlighting is a big one.  A lot of Java projects use Gradle, and Gradle configuration (written in Groovy) is core to a lot of Java minimal reproducible examples.  I think there's a lot of win adding this.