# Fixing complex syntax highlighting of existing posts

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I noticed when reading [Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) that the syntax:

```
<!-- language: lang-foo -->

    something in the Foo programming language
```

is not supported any more. (Why? I couldn't find the reason, but maybe I just missed it.) Yet **a very large number of existing questions and answers were written to use that style. What should be done about them?**

This is a particularly pressing problem on more complex questions about inter-language integration and comparison, as the code snippets are not in a single language determined by the tags on the question. What's more, this style of language indication is going to be fairly common precisely because it was the simplest adaptation of the style that was produced by the post-writing support UI: doing a cut-n-paste job to fix up the highlighting used to be a quick job because it was always pasting whole lines.

“Solutions” involving volunteers going through potentially thousands of posts *each* to find places to fix are non-starters. There's no easy way to search for where the issue might be present, and the amount of effort to apply all the fixes correctly is going to be significant. To my mind at least, it would be easier to reverse the decision to not support the `<!-- language: ... -->` syntax as that only involves a small number of people having to work and produces things that can be applied across the whole database of posts easily.

Comment: First of all, that style is merely deprecated, not removed, and there was a comment on the post you linked saying that they don't currently plan on removing it and there will be an announcement if/when it would be removed. Second, there is an alternative, preferred method of overriding syntax highlighting languages, using the code fence method, outlined in our FAQ on syntax highlighting, [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: From what I see, only the lang-none was removed. Do you have link to a post where the formatting isn't working for prettify using the old style? (see also [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter#comment1183497_354085) by a dev)

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog The issues with the code fence style are that there's many existing code snippets using the other style. Also, highlight.js screws the pooch badly on many languages.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I wrote this question having read that comment.