# Add syntax highlighting support for Nim

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

[Highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) supports syntax highlighting for Nim [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/nim.js). Questions on Stack Overflow for [nim-lang] currently have no highlighting support, and this would be a valued feature for users.

Comment: The Nim grammar is 2069 bytes before compression. And Nim is an awesome language to boot. :-)

Comment: Shortcuts: [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim_(programming_language)) (Wikipedia). [Stack Overflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang) (the tag wiki is somewhat weasel wordy).

Comment: @P.Mort. - forgot Clay Shirky_q thanks for the edit, and umm, are we related? Or is your username just prophetic of mine

Comment: No, it is literally "Shirky" and refers to the sociologist [Clay Shirky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_Shirky) whose [work on Internet phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_Comes_Everybody) formed much of the basis for the initial design of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange (which the company, *probably* out of pure ignorance, seems to be in the process of forgetting (and thus are bound to repeat [the mistakes of the past](https://www.gwern.net/docs/technology/2005-shirky-agroupisitsownworstenemy.pdf))).

Comment: "q" is because question marks are not allowed in user names.

Comment: A similar question was posted on MSO: *[Add support to Stack Overflow for highlighting Nim code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402194)*

Comment: For anyone interested in beta testing or contributing I wrote a Chrome extension that adds support (when hinted) for all supported languages in the core library. It also bundles a much more recent version of the Highlight.js library. https://github.com/joshgoebel/se_highlightjs