# Has there been a recent font change?

Tags: support, design, fonts

I just noticed that the font looks completely different in two places:

1. In code blocks and inline code.

   [image: Screenshot of a comment with inline code]
2. In the editor (old and new).

   [image: Screenshot of some text being typed in the editor]

Maybe it's just me but this font sort of looks "funny". Has there been a recent change in font or is this some sort of bug?

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit; tested on the latest version of both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Possibly related/relevant: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048).

Comment: Also possibly related: [Switching to highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/560258)

Comment: @Rob Yes, apparently this is just on my system. Not sure how it happened or if that font was installed recently. Could've been triggered by a recent Windows update or by the installation of a new version of Visual Studion. Those are the two things I did recently.

Comment: Yes, most likely because of Visual Studio 2022. This font looks... not so great. It's too heavy.