# Why are these 2 code tables rendered differently?

Tags: support, markdown, code-block

When rendered in dark mode, one table has golden borders, the other one has white+grey borders. Despite they are using the same markdown, only content is different.

[image: two code tables with different color highlights]

Please explain why.

My question is about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59683160/1429387) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Because highlight.js thinks the first snippet is YAML and the second Lua (inspect the code elements to find out).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not Markdown tables, these are just code formatted text.

[Code is syntax highlighted using highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) where possible, and when no language tag is given, the language of the code block is determined by the contents.

It was determined that the first code block contains YAML, and the second Lua. These languages have different syntax highlighting colours, so the code is coloured differently.

If you want an actual Markdown table, don't code format it.